# Javascript call() & apply() vs bind()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, this

I already know that `apply` and `call` are similar functions which set `this` (context of a function).

The difference is with the way we send the arguments (manual vs array)

**Question:**

But when should I use the  `bind()` method ?

```
var obj = {
  x: 81,
  getX: function() {
    return this.x;
  }
};

alert(obj.getX.bind(obj)());
alert(obj.getX.call(obj));
alert(obj.getX.apply(obj));
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/awewof/1/edit)

Comment: It's not your fault if there are users that look at the OP's reputation points before posting an answer or upvoting :)

Comment: [**call**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [**apply**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) call a function while [**bind**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) creates a function. Though with `call()` you pass arguments individually and `apply()` as an argument array. For more details check out the linked documentation which should be able to completely answer your question.

Comment: `kind of weird there is not an existing question about this :` Regarding that. That is probably because `bind()` was added after the other two already existed in JavaScript 1.8.5 - ECMA-262, 5th edition. While `call()` and `apply()` have been around since JavaScript 1.3 - ECMA-262 3rd Edition. SO has questions on them like: [**what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply). I'm only guessing though as I was wondering that myself.

Comment: do you need these methods(call,apply,bind) here ?? without this you can also call the method and this will point to object only

Comment: @Nope If I am right, `bind` is like `map`. `map` creates a new array and `bind` creates a new function. Am I?

Comment: Is this the same "call" as in "Array.prototype.slice.call", which is also hard to understand?

Comment: Is obj.call(arg) the same as func(arg) except that "this" is set to obj in the former, to implement class instance methods?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of the JavaScript 'bind' method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

Answer (score 273, accepted):

I created this comparison between function objects, function calls, `call/apply` and `bind` a while ago:

[image]

`.bind` allows you to set the `this` value *now* while allowing you to execute the function *in the future*, because it returns a new function object.

Answer (score 910):

Use `.bind()` when you want that function to later be called with a certain context, useful in events. Use `.call()` or `.apply()` when you want to invoke the function immediately, and modify the context.

Call/apply call the function immediately, whereas `bind` returns a function that, when later executed, will have the correct context set for calling the original function. This way you can maintain context in async callbacks and events.

I do this a lot:

```
function MyObject(element) {
    this.elm = element;

    element.addEventListener('click', this.onClick.bind(this), false);
};

MyObject.prototype.onClick = function(e) {
     var t=this;  //do something with [t]...
    //without bind the context of this function wouldn't be a MyObject
    //instance as you would normally expect.
};
```

I use it extensively in Node.js for async callbacks that I want to pass a member method for, but still want the context to be the instance that started the async action.

A simple, naive implementation of bind would be like:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(ctx) {
    var fn = this;
    return function() {
        fn.apply(ctx, arguments);
    };
};
```

There is more to it (like passing other args), but you can read more about it and see the real implementation [on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: @RoyiNamir that is correct, you can use the returned "bound" function later, and the context will be maintained.

Comment: That is exactly what `bind` returns.

Comment: You can also use bind for partials, passing in arguments before the function is called.

Comment: As an alternative for events I believe you can provide the handleEvent method on your prototype and then pass `this` itself as the event handler.

Comment: So why wouldn't one use `function (){this.onClick.apply(this)})` rather than `call` in order to be compatible with earlier browser versions? Any downside to such an approach?

Comment: @Karl That doesn't work, `this` in that function refers to the context that the function you just listed is called in. If you pass that to say a DOM event, `this` will be the target of the event.

Comment: I see that in my haste, I didn't post the snippet correctly. It should have been something like this `return this.element.addEventListener(event, function () {callback.call(caller);` Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2j916znm/). Since `call` works with older browsers, it seems using it is a better choice than using `bind` unless `bind` is bringing something else to the party? (Naturally `element` and `caller` have been correctly initialized as the fiddle shows.)

Comment: You are just reimplementing bind, there isn't really a difference. Either way you are just wrapping it in a closure that has access to a scope variable that holds the context. Your code is basically the polyfill I posted.

Comment: @Chad If the function is `function test(a,b,c){..}` which one among `call` & `apply` should we use to get values in actual params a,b,c inside the function?

Comment: @techie_28 `.call` and `.apply` do the same thing, just in a different way: `test.call(null, 1, 2, 3);` or `test.call(null, [1, 2, 3]);` will both set `a = 1`, `b = 2`, and `c = 3`.

Comment: @Chad yes thanks.. that was a silly comment from me..I was thinking that `.call` sends params to the arguments local var only..

Comment: @Chad Is it possible to use `.call` or `.apply` or anything in this manner `abc(10,20).call(paramObj)`.I am stripping out a function written in onClick attrib of a button & then have to call it with an extra param.Function is written like `return abc(10,20)`.The extra param could be a string or an object etc.

Comment: `return abc.call(null, 10, 20, paramObj)` But if you are not modifying the context of the fn, there is no need for .call: `abc(10, 20, paramObj)`

Comment: @Chad this is a very clear explanation, thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you forget to declare `arguments` in `return function( /*here*/ ) {...`?

Comment: Nope, arguments is a special object available inside funcitons. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 525):

They all attach ***this*** into function (or object) and the difference is in the function invocation (see below).

**call** attaches ***this*** into function and executes the function immediately:

```
var person = {  
  name: "James Smith",
  hello: function(thing) {
    console.log(this.name + " says hello " + thing);
  }
}

person.hello("world");  // output: "James Smith says hello world"
person.hello.call({ name: "Jim Smith" }, "world"); // output: "Jim Smith says hello world"
```

**bind** attaches ***this*** into function and it needs to be invoked separately like this:

```
var person = {  
  name: "James Smith",
  hello: function(thing) {
    console.log(this.name + " says hello " + thing);
  }
}

person.hello("world");  // output: "James Smith says hello world"
var helloFunc = person.hello.bind({ name: "Jim Smith" });
helloFunc("world");  // output: Jim Smith says hello world"
```

or like this:

```
...    
var helloFunc = person.hello.bind({ name: "Jim Smith" }, "world");
helloFunc();  // output: Jim Smith says hello world"
```

**apply** is similar to **call** except that it takes an array-like object instead of listing the arguments out one at a time:

```
function personContainer() {
  var person = {  
     name: "James Smith",
     hello: function() {
       console.log(this.name + " says hello " + arguments[1]);
     }
  }
  person.hello.apply(person, arguments);
}
personContainer("world", "mars"); // output: "James Smith says hello mars", note: arguments[0] = "world" , arguments[1] = "mars"
```

Comment: Does this mean the difference is that Bind is a Closure?

Comment: You just taught me about arguments feature used inside a function through your code snippet. It is advisable to mention `"use strict"` to avoid overriding such reserved keywords. +1.

Comment: @Max agreed; I've submitted an edit wherein "this" is wrong or makes no sense until we use bind/call/apply

Comment: Thanks for the improvement suggestions. I edited my answer a bit. @iono Your suggestion had some inaccuracies so couldn't approve it, but did my own edits in the answer. Hopefully it is now more comprehensive.

Answer (score 327):

> Answer in SIMPLEST form

- *Call* invokes the function and allows you to pass in arguments one by
  one.
- *Apply* invokes the function and allows you to pass in arguments
  as an array.
- *Bind* returns a new function, allowing you to pass in a
  this array and any number of arguments.

---

### Apply vs. Call vs. Bind Examples

**Call**

```
var person1 = {firstName: 'Jon', lastName: 'Kuperman'};
var person2 = {firstName: 'Kelly', lastName: 'King'};

function say(greeting) {
    console.log(greeting + ' ' + this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName);
}

say.call(person1, 'Hello'); // Hello Jon Kuperman
say.call(person2, 'Hello'); // Hello Kelly King
```

**Apply**

```
var person1 = {firstName: 'Jon', lastName: 'Kuperman'};
var person2 = {firstName: 'Kelly', lastName: 'King'};

function say(greeting) {
    console.log(greeting + ' ' + this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName);
}

say.apply(person1, ['Hello']); // Hello Jon Kuperman
say.apply(person2, ['Hello']); // Hello Kelly King
```

**Bind**

```
var person1 = {firstName: 'Jon', lastName: 'Kuperman'};
var person2 = {firstName: 'Kelly', lastName: 'King'};

function say() {
    console.log('Hello ' + this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName);
}

var sayHelloJon = say.bind(person1);
var sayHelloKelly = say.bind(person2);

sayHelloJon(); // Hello Jon Kuperman
sayHelloKelly(); // Hello Kelly King
```

### When To Use Each

Call and apply are pretty interchangeable. Just decide whether it’s easier to send in an array or a comma separated list of arguments.

I always remember which one is which by remembering that Call is for comma (separated list) and Apply is for Array.

Bind is a bit different. It returns a new function. Call and Apply execute the current function immediately.

Bind is great for a lot of things. We can use it to curry functions like in the above example. We can take a simple hello function and turn it into a helloJon or helloKelly. We can also use it for events like onClick where we don’t know when they’ll be fired but we know what context we want them to have.

Reference: [codeplanet.io](https://codeplanet.io/javascript-apply-vs-call-vs-bind/)

Comment: In `call` and `apply`, does it follow that if you don't have a `this` inside the method, then you would assign the first argument as a `null`?

Comment: @DaryllSantos, According to MDN:thisArg 
Optional. The value of this provided for the call to a function. Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in non-strict mode , null and undefined will be replaced with the global object and primitive values will be converted to objects.

So if you don't use this in the function it doesn't matter.

Comment: call = = comma, apply == array was a nice little memorization trick

Comment: `var person1 = {firstName: 'Jon', lastName: 'Kuperman'};

function say(greeting) {
    console.log(greeting + ' ' + this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName);
}

say.apply(person1, ['Hello']); // Hello Jon Kuperman`
Works perfectly fine and outputs
VM128:4 Hello Jon Kuperman

Answer (score 83):

**TL;DR:**

In simple words, bind creates the function, call and apply executes the function whereas apply expects the parameters in array

**Full Explanation**

Assume we have `multiplication` function

```
function multiplication(a,b){
console.log(a*b);
}
```

Lets create some standard functions using `bind`

`var multiby2 = multiplication.bind(this,2);`

Now multiby2(b) is equal to multiplication(2,b);

```
multiby2(3); //6
multiby2(4); //8
```

What if I pass both the parameters in bind

```
var getSixAlways = multiplication.bind(this,3,2);
```

Now getSixAlways() is equal to multiplication(3,2);

```
getSixAlways();//6
```

even passing parameter returns 6;
`getSixAlways(12); //6`

```
var magicMultiplication = multiplication.bind(this);
```

This create a new multiplication function and assigns it to magicMultiplication.

Oh no, we are hiding the multiplication functionality into magicMultiplication.

calling
`magicMultiplication` returns a blank `function b()`

on execution it works fine
`magicMultiplication(6,5); //30`

How about call and apply?

`magicMultiplication.call(this,3,2); //6`

`magicMultiplication.apply(this,[5,2]); //10`

Comment: Very well explained!

Comment: +1 for "In simple words, `bind` creates the function, `call` and `apply` executes the function whereas `apply` expects the parameters in array"

Comment: What is function b, and why is it blank?

Comment: @DavidSpector, it is not function b. It is a function that takes an argument named 'b' because of how the function "multiplication" was defined with 'a' and 'b' as arguments. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 57):

It allows to set the value for `this` independent of how the function is called. This is very useful when working with callbacks:

```
  function sayHello(){
    alert(this.message);
  }

  var obj = {
     message : "hello"
  };
  setTimeout(sayHello.bind(obj), 1000);
```

To achieve the same result with `call` would look like this:

```
  function sayHello(){
    alert(this.message);
  }

  var obj = {
     message : "hello"
  };
  setTimeout(function(){sayHello.call(obj)}, 1000);
```

Comment: Usage of `.bind()` like you've showed before is incorrect. When you use `fn.bind(obj)` other function will be returned (not that you've create before). And there are no abilities to change value of `this` inside of `binded` function. Mostly this is used for callbacks `this` insurance. But in yours example - there are no differences in result. But `fn !== fn.bind(obj);` Notice that.

Comment: @InviS I don't understand your comment - why is there no different?

Comment: The difference in call and apply is.
in call you pass arguments as comma separated strings, while in
apply you can pass arguments in form of array.
rest the are same.

Comment: comma separated **strings**??  just  *pass arguments as comma separated* !!

Answer (score 48):

The main concept behind all these methods is **Function borrowing**.

Function borrowing allows us to use the methods of one object on a different object without having to make a copy of that method and maintain it in two separate places. It is accomplished through the use of `.call()`, `.apply()`, or `.bind()`, all of which exist to explicitly set this on the method we are borrowing.

1. **`Call`** invokes the function immediately and allows you to pass in arguments one by one.
2. **`Apply`** invokes the function immediately and allows you to pass in arguments as an **array**.
3. **`Bind`** returns a new function, and you can invoke/call it anytime you want by invoking a function.

Below is an example of all this methods:

```js
let name = {
    firstName: "Arham",
    lastName: "Chowdhury",
}

printFullName = function(hometown, company) {
    console.log(`${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}, ${hometown}, ${company}`);
}
```

**`CALL`**

> the first argument e.g name inside call method is always a reference to (this) variable and latter will be function variable:

```js
printFullName.call(name, "Mumbai", "Taufa"); //Arham Chowdhury, Mumbai, Taufa
```

**`APPLY`**

> `apply()` method is same as the `call()` method, the only difference is that, the function arguments are passed in array list:

```js
printFullName.apply(name, ["Mumbai", "Taufa"]); //Arham Chowdhury, Mumbai, Taufa
```

**`BIND`**

> `bind()` method is same as `call()` except that ,the `bind()` returns a function that can be used later by invoking it — it isn't called automatically immediately:

```js
let printMyName = printFullName.bind(name, "Mumbai", "Taufa");

printMyName(); //Arham Chowdhury, Mumbai, Taufa
```

`printMyName()` is the function which invokes the function.

A [playground](https://codepen.io/Arham11/pen/vYNqExp) on Codepen.io.

Comment: this is a very nice explanation

Comment: Thankyou @DarioushPD

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this nice explanation

Comment: This is well explained. Thanks @ArhamChowdhury

Comment: What happens if I pass array to call method ? as I checked it works fine. Can you please explain it.

Comment: @Vasanth "call" would not be a good option to use for argument passed as an array.

In the above example if you use "call" with an array it would append "undefined" in the end.

If there is more then one argument expected then "undefined" would be more.

Answer (score 38):

Both [**`Function.prototype.call()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [**`Function.prototype.apply()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) call a function with a given `this` value, and return the return value of that function.

[**`Function.prototype.bind()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), on the other hand, creates a new function with a given `this` value, and returns that function without executing it.

So, let's take a function that looks like this :

```
var logProp = function(prop) {
    console.log(this[prop]);
};
```

Now, let's take an object that looks like this :

```
var Obj = {
    x : 5,
    y : 10
};
```

We can bind our function to our object like this :

```
Obj.log = logProp.bind(Obj);
```

Now, we can run `Obj.log` anywhere in our code :

```
Obj.log('x'); // Output : 5
Obj.log('y'); // Output : 10
```

---

Where it really gets interesting, is when you not only bind a value for `this`, but also for for its argument `prop` :

```
Obj.logX = logProp.bind(Obj, 'x');
Obj.logY = logProp.bind(Obj, 'y');
```

We can now do this :

```
Obj.logX(); // Output : 5
Obj.logY(); // Output : 10
```

Answer (score 28):

**bind**: It binds the function with provided value and context but it does not executes the function. To execute function you need to call the function.

**call**: It executes the function with provided context and parameter.

**apply**: It executes the function with provided context and 
**parameter as array**.

Comment: simple and humble!

Answer (score 21):

Here is one [good article](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/) to illustrate the difference among `bind()`, `apply()` and `call()`, summarize it as below.

- `bind()` allows us to easily set which specific object will be bound to *this* when a function or method is invoked.

  ```
  // This data variable is a global variable​
  var data = [
      {name:"Samantha", age:12},
      {name:"Alexis", age:14}
  ]
  var user = {
      // local data variable​
      data    :[
          {name:"T. Woods", age:37},
          {name:"P. Mickelson", age:43}
      ],
      showData:function (event) {
          var randomNum = ((Math.random () * 2 | 0) + 1) - 1; // random number between 0 and 1​
          console.log (this.data[randomNum].name + " " + this.data[randomNum].age);
      }
  }

  // Assign the showData method of the user object to a variable​
  var showDataVar = user.showData;
  showDataVar (); // Samantha 12 (from the global data array, not from the local data array)​
  /*
  This happens because showDataVar () is executed as a global function and use of this inside 
  showDataVar () is bound to the global scope, which is the window object in browsers.
  */

  // Bind the showData method to the user object​
  var showDataVar = user.showData.bind (user);
  // Now the we get the value from the user object because the this keyword is bound to the user object​
  showDataVar (); // P. Mickelson 43​
  ```
- `bind()` allow us to borrow methods

  ```
  // Here we have a cars object that does not have a method to print its data to the console​
  var cars = {
      data:[
         {name:"Honda Accord", age:14},
         {name:"Tesla Model S", age:2}
     ]
  }

  // We can borrow the showData () method from the user object we defined in the last example.​
  // Here we bind the user.showData method to the cars object we just created.​
  cars.showData = user.showData.bind (cars);
  cars.showData (); // Honda Accord 14​
  ```

  One problem with this example is that we are adding a new method `showData` on the `cars` object and 
  we might not want to do that just to borrow a method because the cars object might already have a property or method name `showData`.
  We don’t want to overwrite it accidentally. As we will see in our discussion of `Apply` and `Call` below, 
  it is best to borrow a method using either the `Apply` or `Call` method.
- `bind()` allow us to curry a function

  [**Function Currying**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), also known as *partial function application*, is the use of a
  function (that accept one or more arguments) that returns a new function with some of the arguments already set.

  ```
  function greet (gender, age, name) {
      // if a male, use Mr., else use Ms.​
      var salutation = gender === "male" ? "Mr. " : "Ms. ";
      if (age > 25) {
          return "Hello, " + salutation + name + ".";
      }else {
          return "Hey, " + name + ".";
      }
   }
  ```

  We can use `bind()` to curry this `greet` function

  ```
  // So we are passing null because we are not using the "this" keyword in our greet function.
  var greetAnAdultMale = greet.bind (null, "male", 45);

  greetAnAdultMale ("John Hartlove"); // "Hello, Mr. John Hartlove."

  var greetAYoungster = greet.bind (null, "", 16);
  greetAYoungster ("Alex"); // "Hey, Alex."​
  greetAYoungster ("Emma Waterloo"); // "Hey, Emma Waterloo."
  ```
- `apply()` or `call()` to set *this* value

  The `apply`, `call`, and `bind` methods are all used to set the this value when invoking a method, and they do it in slightly
  different ways to allow use direct control and versatility in our JavaScript code.

  The `apply` and `call` methods are almost identical when setting the this value except that you pass the function parameters to `apply ()` as *an array*, while you have to *list the parameters individually* to pass them to the `call ()` method.

  Here is one example to use `call` or `apply` to set *this* in the callback function.

  ```
  // Define an object with some properties and a method​
  // We will later pass the method as a callback function to another function​
  var clientData = {
      id: 094545,
      fullName: "Not Set",
      // setUserName is a method on the clientData object​
      setUserName: function (firstName, lastName)  {
          // this refers to the fullName property in this object​
          this.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
      }
  };

  function getUserInput (firstName, lastName, callback, callbackObj) {
       // The use of the Apply method below will set the "this" value to callbackObj​
       callback.apply (callbackObj, [firstName, lastName]);
  }

  // The clientData object will be used by the Apply method to set the "this" value​
  getUserInput ("Barack", "Obama", clientData.setUserName, clientData);
  // the fullName property on the clientData was correctly set​
  console.log (clientData.fullName); // Barack Obama
  ```
- Borrow functions with `apply` or `call`

  - Borrow Array methods

    Let’s create an `array-like` object and borrow some array methods to operate on the our array-like object.

    ```
    // An array-like object: note the non-negative integers used as keys​
    var anArrayLikeObj = {0:"Martin", 1:78, 2:67, 3:["Letta", "Marieta", "Pauline"], length:4 };

     // Make a quick copy and save the results in a real array:
     // First parameter sets the "this" value​
     var newArray = Array.prototype.slice.call (anArrayLikeObj, 0);
     console.log (newArray); // ["Martin", 78, 67, Array[3]]​

     // Search for "Martin" in the array-like object​
     console.log (Array.prototype.indexOf.call (anArrayLikeObj, "Martin") === -1 ? false : true); // true​
    ```

    Another common case is that convert `arguments` to array as following

    ```
      // We do not define the function with any parameters, yet we can get all the arguments passed to it​
     function doSomething () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call (arguments);
        console.log (args);
     }

     doSomething ("Water", "Salt", "Glue"); // ["Water", "Salt", "Glue"]
    ```
  - Borrow other methods

    ```
    var gameController = {
         scores  :[20, 34, 55, 46, 77],
         avgScore:null,
         players :[
              {name:"Tommy", playerID:987, age:23},
              {name:"Pau", playerID:87, age:33}
         ]
     }
     var appController = {
         scores  :[900, 845, 809, 950],
         avgScore:null,
         avg     :function () {
                 var sumOfScores = this.scores.reduce (function (prev, cur, index, array) {
                      return prev + cur;
             });
             this.avgScore = sumOfScores / this.scores.length;
         }
       }
       // Note that we are using the apply () method, so the 2nd argument has to be an array​
       appController.avg.apply (gameController);
       console.log (gameController.avgScore); // 46.4​
       // appController.avgScore is still null; it was not updated, only gameController.avgScore was updated​
       console.log (appController.avgScore); // null​
    ```
- Use `apply()` to execute *variable-arity* function

The [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) is one example of variable-arity function,

```
// We can pass any number of arguments to the Math.max () method​
console.log (Math.max (23, 11, 34, 56)); // 56
```

But what if we have an array of numbers to pass to `Math.max`? We cannot do this:

```
var allNumbers = [23, 11, 34, 56];
// We cannot pass an array of numbers to the the Math.max method like this​
console.log (Math.max (allNumbers)); // NaN
```

This is where the `apply ()` method helps us execute *variadic functions*. Instead of the above, we have to pass the array of numbers using `apply (`) thus:

```
var allNumbers = [23, 11, 34, 56];
// Using the apply () method, we can pass the array of numbers:
console.log (Math.max.apply (null, allNumbers)); // 56
```

Answer (score 12):

The basic difference between Call, Apply and Bind are:

Bind will be used if you want your execution context to come later in the picture.

Ex:

```
var car = { 
  registrationNumber: "007",
  brand: "Mercedes",

  displayDetails: function(ownerName){
    console.log(ownerName + ' this is your car ' + '' + this.registrationNumber + " " + this.brand);
  }
}
car.displayDetails('Nishant'); // **Nishant this is your car 007 Mercedes**
```

Let's say i want use this method in some other variable

```
var car1 = car.displayDetails('Nishant');
car1(); // undefined
```

To use the reference of car in some other variable you should use

```
var car1 = car.displayDetails.bind(car, 'Nishant');
car1(); // Nishant this is your car 007 Mercedes
```

Let's talk about more extensive use of bind function

```
var func = function() {
 console.log(this)
}.bind(1);

func();
// Number: 1
```

Why? Because now func is bind with Number 1, if we don't use bind in that case it will point to Global Object.

```
var func = function() {
 console.log(this)
}.bind({});

func();
// Object
```

Call, Apply are used when you want to execute the statement at the same time.

```
var Name = { 
    work: "SSE",
    age: "25"
}

function displayDetails(ownerName) {
    console.log(ownerName + ", this is your name: " + 'age' + this.age + " " + 'work' + this.work);
}
displayDetails.call(Name, 'Nishant')
// Nishant, this is your name: age25 workSSE

// In apply we pass an array of arguments
displayDetails.apply(Name, ['Nishant'])
// Nishant, this is your name: age25 workSSE
```

Answer (score 11):

**call/apply** executes function immediately:

```
func.call(context, arguments);
func.apply(context, [argument1,argument2,..]);
```

**bind** doesn't execute function immediately, but returns wrapped *apply* function (for later execution):

```
function bind(func, context) {
    return function() {
        return func.apply(context, arguments);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Call apply and bind. and how they are different.**

Lets learn call and apply using any daily terminology.

You have three automobiles `your_scooter , your_car and your_jet` which start with the same mechanism (method). 
We created an object `automobile` with a method `push_button_engineStart`.

```
var your_scooter, your_car, your_jet;
var automobile = {
        push_button_engineStart: function (runtime){
        console.log(this.name + "'s" + ' engine_started, buckle up for the ride for ' + runtime + " minutes");
    }
}
```

Lets understand when is call and apply used. Lets suppose that you are an engineer and you have `your_scooter`, `your_car` and `your_jet` which did not come with a push_button_engine_start and you wish to use a third party `push_button_engineStart`.

If you run the following lines of code, they will give an error. WHY?

```
//your_scooter.push_button_engineStart();
//your_car.push_button_engineStart();
//your_jet.push_button_engineStart();


automobile.push_button_engineStart.apply(your_scooter,[20]);
automobile.push_button_engineStart.call(your_jet,10);
automobile.push_button_engineStart.call(your_car,40);
```

So the above example is successfully gives your_scooter, your_car, your_jet a feature from automobile object.

**Let's dive deeper**
Here we will split the above line of code. 
`automobile.push_button_engineStart` is helping us to get the method being used.

Further we use apply or call using the dot notation. 
`automobile.push_button_engineStart.apply()`

Now apply and call accept two parameters.

1. context
2. arguments

So here we set the context in the final line of code.

`automobile.push_button_engineStart.apply(your_scooter,[20])`

**Difference between call and apply** is just that apply accepts parameters in the form of an array while call simply can accept a comma separated list of arguments.

**what is JS Bind function?**

A bind function is basically which binds the context of something and then stores it into a variable for execution at a later stage.

Let's make our previous example even better. Earlier we used a method belonging to the automobile object and used it to equip `your_car, your_jet and your_scooter`. Now lets imagine we want to give a separate `push_button_engineStart` separately to start our automobiles individually at any later stage of the execution we wish.

```
var scooty_engineStart = automobile.push_button_engineStart.bind(your_scooter);
var car_engineStart = automobile.push_button_engineStart.bind(your_car);
var jet_engineStart = automobile.push_button_engineStart.bind(your_jet);


setTimeout(scooty_engineStart,5000,30);
setTimeout(car_engineStart,10000,40);
setTimeout(jet_engineStart,15000,5);
```

***still not satisfied?***

Let's make it clear as teardrop. Time to experiment. We will go back to call and apply function application and try storing the value of the function as a reference.

The experiment below fails because call and apply are invoked immediately, hence, we never get to the stage of storing a reference in a variable which is where bind function steals the show

`var test_function = automobile.push_button_engineStart.apply(your_scooter);`

Answer (score 9):

Syntax

- **call**(thisArg, arg1, arg2, ...)
- **apply**(thisArg, argsArray)
- **bind**(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])

Here

- thisArg is the object
- argArray is an array object
- arg1, arg2, arg3,... are additional arguments

```js
function printBye(message1, message2){
    console.log(message1 + " " + this.name + " "+ message2);
}

var par01 = { name:"John" };
var msgArray = ["Bye", "Never come again..."];

printBye.call(par01, "Bye", "Never come again...");
//Bye John Never come again...

printBye.call(par01, msgArray);
//Bye,Never come again... John undefined

//so call() doesn't work with array and better with comma seperated parameters 

//printBye.apply(par01, "Bye", "Never come again...");//Error

printBye.apply(par01, msgArray);
//Bye John Never come again...

var func1 = printBye.bind(par01, "Bye", "Never come again...");
func1();//Bye John Never come again...

var func2 = printBye.bind(par01, msgArray);
func2();//Bye,Never come again... John undefined
//so bind() doesn't work with array and better with comma seperated parameters
```

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript Call()

```
const person = {
    name: "Lokamn",
    dob: 12,
    print: function (value,value2) {
        console.log(this.dob+value+value2)
    }
}
const anotherPerson= {
     name: "Pappu",
     dob: 12,
}
 person.print.call(anotherPerson,1,2)
```

## JavaScript apply()

```
    name: "Lokamn",
    dob: 12,
    print: function (value,value2) {
        console.log(this.dob+value+value2)
    }
}
const anotherPerson= {
     name: "Pappu",
     dob: 12,
}
 person.print.apply(anotherPerson,[1,2])
```

**call and apply function are difference call take separate argument but apply take array 
like:[1,2,3]
**

## JavaScript bind()

```
    name: "Lokamn",
    dob: 12,
    anotherPerson: {
        name: "Pappu",
        dob: 12,
        print2: function () {
            console.log(this)
        }
    }
}

var bindFunction = person.anotherPerson.print2.bind(person)
 bindFunction()
```

Answer (score 5):

**Call:** call invokes the function and allows you to pass arguments one by one

**Apply:** Apply invokes the function and allows you to pass arguments as an array

**Bind:** Bind returns a new function, allowing you to pass in a this array and any number of arguments.

```js
var person1 = {firstName: 'Raju', lastName: 'king'};
var person2 = {firstName: 'chandu', lastName: 'shekar'};

function greet(greeting) {
    console.log(greeting + ' ' + this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName);
}
function greet2(greeting) {
        console.log( 'Hello ' + this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName);
    }


greet.call(person1, 'Hello'); // Hello Raju king
greet.call(person2, 'Hello'); // Hello chandu shekar



greet.apply(person1, ['Hello']); // Hello Raju king
greet.apply(person2, ['Hello']); // Hello chandu shekar

var greetRaju = greet2.bind(person1);
var greetChandu = greet2.bind(person2);

greetRaju(); // Hello Raju king
greetChandu(); // Hello chandu shekar
```

Answer (score 5):

**call() :--**  Here we pass the function arguments individually, not in an array format

```
var obj = {name: "Raushan"};

var greeting = function(a,b,c) {
    return "Welcome "+ this.name + " to "+ a + " " + b + " in " + c;
};

console.log(greeting.call(obj, "USA", "INDIA", "ASIA"));
```

**apply() :--**  Here we pass the function arguments in an array format

```
var obj = {name: "Raushan"};

var cal = function(a,b,c) {
    return this.name +" you got " + a+b+c;
};

var arr =[1,2,3];  // array format for function arguments
console.log(cal.apply(obj, arr));
```

**bind() :--**

```
       var obj = {name: "Raushan"};

       var cal = function(a,b,c) {
            return this.name +" you got " + a+b+c;
       };

       var calc = cal.bind(obj);
       console.log(calc(2,3,4));
```

Answer (score 3):

Imagine, bind is not available. 
you can easily construct it as follow :

```
var someFunction=...
var objToBind=....

var bindHelper =  function (someFunction, objToBind) {
    return function() {
        someFunction.apply( objToBind, arguments );
    };  
}

bindHelper(arguments);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    function sayHello() {
            //alert(this.message);
            return this.message;
    }
    var obj = {
            message: "Hello"
    };

    function x(country) {
            var z = sayHello.bind(obj);
            setTimeout(y = function(w) {
//'this' reference not lost
                    return z() + ' ' + country + ' ' + w;
            }, 1000);
            return y;
    }
    var t = x('India')('World');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use bind for future calls to the function. Both `apply` and `call` invoke the function.

`bind()` also allows for additional arguments to be perpended to the args array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 0):

**In simple terms, all methods are used to set the context(this) explicitly in the regular function**

Call: call invokes the function on given context and allows to pass arguments one by one

Apply: apply invokes the function on given context and allows to pass arguments as an array

Bind: bind returns a new function by setting the provided context, and allows to pass arguments one by one

**Notes:**

1. Call and Apply both are similar only difference is the way they expect arguments
2. The mentioned methods do not work with arrow function

Answer (score 0):

The first difference between call(), apply(), and bind() methods in JavaScript is their time of execution!
call() and apply() being similar are executed instantly, whereas, bind() creates a new function which we have to explicitly call at any later point of time!

Another difference is, that while passing arguments, call() allows us to pass one by one separated by commas, apply() allows us to pass as an array of arguments, and bind() allows us to do both!

I have attached the example code below!

```
const person = {
    fullName : function (randomMessage) {
        return `Hello, ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName} ${randomMessage}`;
    }
}

const personOne = {
    firstName : "John",
    lastName : "Doe"
}

const personTwo = {
    firstName : "Jack",
    lastName : "Adhikari"
}

let fullNameBind = person.fullName.bind(personOne, "--Binding");
let fullNameCall = person.fullName.call({firstName : "Sarah", lastName: "Holmes"}, "--Calling");
let fullNameApply = person.fullName.apply(personTwo, ["--Applying"]);

console.log(fullNameBind());
console.log(fullNameCall);
console.log(fullNameApply);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the same places of them are: all of them can change the this value of a function.The differences of them are: the bind function will return a new function as a result; the call and apply methods will execute the function immediately, but apply can accept a array as params,and it will parse the array separated.And also, the bind function can be Currying.

Answer (score -3):

bind function should be use when we want to assign a function with particular context for eg.

```
var demo = {
           getValue : function(){ 
             console.log('demo object get value       function') 
            }
           setValue : function(){  
              setTimeout(this.getValue.bind(this),1000)           
           }
 }
```

in above example if we call demo.setValue() function and pass this.getValue function directly then it doesn't call demo.setValue function directly because this in setTimeout refers to window object so  we need to pass demo object context to this.getValue function using bind. it means we only passing function with the context of demo object not actully calling function.

Hope u understand .

for more information please refer 
[javascript bind function know in detail](http://www.angularjspassion.in/2016/12/javascript-bind-function.html)