# what's the difference between 'call/apply' and 'bind'

Tags: javascript, function, call, bind, apply

```
var obj = {
   x: 81,
   getX: function() { 
     console.log( this.x) 
   }
};
var getX = obj.getX.bind(obj);//use obj as 'this';
getX();//81
var getX = function(){
  obj.getX.apply(obj); 
}
getX();//also 81
```

The use of bind and call/apply look very similar, I want to know what's the difference between them.The two getX Function above is the same?

Comment: Check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/js-call-apply-vs-bind

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`bind` returns a function which will act like the original function but with `this` predefined. It is usually used when you want to pass a function to an event handler or other async callback.

`call` and `apply` will call a function immediately letting you specify both the value of `this` and any arguments the function will receive.

Your second example defines an anonymous function which calls `apply`. This is a common pattern; `bind` provides a standard implementation of that which allows you to do it with a simple function call (thus being quicker and easier to write).

Comment: Also, you can specify arguments in the `bind()` call that will be prepended to the argument list when you call the resulting function, e.g. `function add(a,b){return a+b}; var plus5=add.bind(null,5); console.log(plus5(6) /*11*/)`

Answer (score 34):

`.call()` - calls the same function with the specified arguments

`.apply()` - calls the same function with the arguments specified in an array

`.bind()` - creates a new function with the same function body, with a preset value of `this` (the first argument) and returns that function.

In all cases, the first argument is used as the value of `this` inside the function.

Comment: How can you talk about `call`, `apply`, and `bind` without discussing `this`?!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Added that bit too.. :)

Comment: ``bind()`` doesn't call the function. Consider rephrasing that.

Comment: I like how short and simple this is!

Comment: totally passes the rubber duck test

Answer (score 5):

The difference is how you make the call. If you've used `bind` to get back a function with a bound `this` value, you just call the function:

```
getx();
```

If you don't have a bound function, and you want to set `this`, you do so with `call` or `apply`:

```
someFunction.call(objectToUseAsThis, arg1, arg2);
// or
someFunction.apply(objectToUseAsThis, [arg1, arg2]);
```

Note that if you have a bound function (like your `getX`), using `call` on it is pointless, because the `this` you supply will just get overridden by the bound `this`. (Using `apply` might still be useful, if you have an array of values you want to ass as arguments.)

Comment: `apply` isn't pointless because you may have an array of args and you can't invoke that directly.

Comment: @Neil: Okay, fair point.