# understanding MDN's example of bind

Tags: javascript

Hey guys i have been trying to learn what the bind() method does in JS and i have found a few helpful resources in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/js-call-apply-vs-bind) , [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and also [git](https://gist.github.com/branneman/5814160) that do explain this rather well , but i am still a bit confused with a practical example that i found on MDN.
The below code i am talking about :

```
function LateBloomer() {
  this.petalCount = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
}

// Declare bloom after a delay of 1 second
LateBloomer.prototype.bloom = function() {
  window.setTimeout(this.declare.bind(this), 1000);
};

LateBloomer.prototype.declare = function() {
  console.log('I am a beautiful flower with ' +
    this.petalCount + ' petals!');
};
```

now bind function just like call() or apply() , thats what i understood so far , but what it does is , it can delay the execution of a function while preserving or rather binding the value of the `this` to a specific function .

now in the below lines of code :

```
LateBloomer.prototype.bloom = function() {
      window.setTimeout(this.declare.bind(this), 1000);
    };
```

what is the 1st `this` pointing to ? and what is the secound `this` pointing to ?

Comment: Both `this` point to the same thing, the object before the dot when you call the function.

Comment: @elclanrs window ?? i taught bind was being used to avoid pointing to the window !

Comment: Bothe refers to the same object instance on which `bloom` was called

Comment: @ArunPJohny inside `LateBloomer.prototype.bloom = function() {` does this refer to `function bloom` or `function LateBloomer` , my guess is the latter !

Comment: In both the times both `this` is used in the method `bloom` so both the times it refers to the same value

Comment: It does not refer to either one... it refers to the object instance of `LateBloomer`

Comment: @ArunPJohny but does't the value of this change inside setTimeout , to point to the global window ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76238/discussion-between-alexander-solonik-and-arun-p-johny).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `this.declare.bind(this)`, the first `this` is used to get the current object's `declare` method. Then we use `bind` to create a new function that will call that method with a specific `this` value, and that's the argument to `bind()`. It just so happens that we're binding it to the current object, so we use `this` in both place, but we don't have to. We could write:

```
var another = new LateBloomer;
setTimeout(this.declare.bind(another), 1000);
```

This gets the current object's `declare` method, and arranges to call it on `another` in 1 second.

Comment: so this in both cases refer to the instance of LateBloomer ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I was trying to describe it in more generality.