# Ember, mixin to detect click outside of view/component

Tags: ember.js

I'm writing a Mixin to handle when user clicks outside of a view/component.

This is the mixin:

```
App.ClickElsewhereMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({

  onClickElsewhere: Ember.K,

  didRender: function() {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    return $(document).on('click', this.get('onClickElsewhere'));
  },

  willDestroyElement: function() {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    $(document).off('click', this.get('onClickElsewhere'));
  },
});
```

I use it in my component:

```
onClickElsewhere: function() {
    this.send('exitEditMode');
},
```

But when I run it, I get:

```
TypeError: this.send is not a function
```

How can I keep the `this` context?

---

### Solution:

just to make it easier for the reader, here the working Mixin:

```
App.ClickElsewhereMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({

  onClickElsewhere: Ember.K,

  setupListener: Ember.on('didRender', function() {
    // Set an event that will be fired when user clicks outside of the component/view
    return $(document).on('click', $.proxy(this.get('onClickElsewhere'), this));
  }),

  removeListener: Ember.on('willDestroyElement', function() {
    // Clean the previously defined event to keep events stack clean
    return $(document).off('click', $.proxy(this.get('onClickElsewhere'), this));
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current answer doesn't check whether the click was actually outside of the element – a click on the component will also trigger the callback.

Here's an updated version:

```
export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  onOutsideClick: Ember.K,

  handleOutsideClick: function(event) {
    let $element = this.$();
    let $target = $(event.target);

    if (!$target.closest($element).length) {
      this.onOutsideClick();
    }
  },

  setupOutsideClickListener: Ember.on('didInsertElement', function() {
    let clickHandler = this.get('handleOutsideClick').bind(this);

    return Ember.$(document).on('click', clickHandler);
  }),

  removeOutsideClickListener: Ember.on('willDestroyElement', function() {
    let clickHandler = this.get('handleOutsideClick').bind(this);

    return Ember.$(document).off('click', clickHandler);
  })
});
```

Comment: So this will not actually remove the listener properly, doing `this.get(...).bind(this)` in each function creates references to *different* functions, so the `document.off(...)` won't identify the listener properly. It should store a reference to the bound function and *use that same reference* in both add/remove

Answer (score 6):

Greg answer have a mistake, that makes removing the clickHandler event not working. Which means that your clickevent will fire even if you destroy the component.

Here is proper version

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
    onOutsideClick: Ember.K,

  handleOutsideClick: function(event) {
    let $element = this.$();
    let $target = $(event.target);

    if (!$target.closest($element).length) {
      this.onOutsideClick();
    }
  },

  setupOutsideClickListener: Ember.on('didInsertElement', function() {

    let clickHandler = this.get('handleOutsideClick').bind(this);

    return Ember.$(document).on('click', clickHandler);
  }),

  removeOutsideClickListener: Ember.on('willDestroyElement', function() {

    let clickHandler = this.get('handleOutsideClick').bind(this);

    return Ember.$(document).off('click', Ember.run.cancel(this, clickHandler));
  })
});
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me thanks a lot. I think the problem was that I was not doing this.get('clickHandler')

Answer (score 4):

The ember way of doing it is [Ember.run.bind](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_bind). This takes care of binding and the run loop.

```
App.ClickElsewhereMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({

  onClickElsewhere: Ember.K,

  setupListener: Ember.on('didRender', function() {
    this.set('clickHandler', Ember.run.bind(this, this.onClickElsewhere));
    Ember.$(document).click(this.get('clickHandler'));
  }),

  removeListener: Ember.on('willDestroyElement', function() {
    Ember.$(document).off('click', this.get('clickHandler'));
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Use a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)
2. Use [`bind`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/bind-method-of-javascript)

#### Closure

```
App.ClickElsewhereMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({

  onClickElsewhere: Ember.K,

  didRender: function() {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    return $(document).on('click', function(this){ return this.get('onClickElsewhere'); }(this));
  },

  willDestroyElement: function() {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    $(document).off('click', function(this){ return this.get('onClickElsewhere'); }(this));
  },
});
```

#### Bind

```
App.ClickElsewhereMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({

  onClickElsewhere: Ember.K,

  didRender: function() {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    return $(document).on('click', this.get('onClickElsewhere').bind(this));
  },

  willDestroyElement: function() {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    $(document).off('click', this.get('onClickElsewhere').bind(this));
  },
});
```

However, not all browsers support bind yet.

Also, I think you need to use `sendAction` instead of `send` in the component (http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/)

**Edit**:

[`jQuery.proxy`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/10399ddcf8a239acc27bdec9231b996b178224d3/test/data/jquery-1.9.1.js#L800-L825) uses `call`/`apply` underneath the covers.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/js-call-apply-vs-bind) for a discussion of `call`/`apply` vs `bind`.

Comment: Actually I have found that I can use the `$.proxy` function of jQuery, what do you think?

Comment: Thanks! Looks like there are lot of ways.

Comment: This does not work because doing `bind` creates references to two different functions, and the `removeEventListener` does not match them up properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the lib [ember-click-outside](https://github.com/zeppelin/ember-click-outside). Worked for me.