# How to detect a click outside an element and send the event by ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My problem look like: [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

But I want to use `ember.js` do this. My template code:

```
<td colspan="2" {{action "changeName" on="doubleClick"}}>
  {{#if isEditName}}
    {{input type="text" value=editName class="form-control"}}
  {{else}}
    {{product.name}}
  {{/if}}
</td>
```

I want to do when I double click the `div`, show `input` and I can change name in `input`. I think when I change name and click the body will save the name. I think is better. But I don't know how to set the event in body, when I click the body will hide `input` and save product.name.

Thanks.

Add a picture to show the behavior process:

[image]

Comment: I solved a similar issue based on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623530/ember-mixin-to-detect-click-outside-of-view-component

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exactly meant but im guessing you're looking for something like this

```
<td>
  {{#if isEditName}}
    <span {{action "showOrHide" on="doubleClick"}}> {{input type="text" value=product.name class="form-control"}}</span>
  {{else}}
     <span {{action 'showOrHide' on="doubleClick"}}> {{product.name}} </span>
  {{/if}}
</td>


isEditName: false,

actions : {
 showOrHide: function() { 
     this.toggleProperty('isEditName'); 

     if(!this.get('isEditName') { // changed from input to detail view
         this.get('product').save();
     }


 })
}
```

Comment: Maybe use `on="doubleClick"` do catch doubleClick instead of click.

Comment: Yeah , changed it. I've never used it so not sure if it works tho =D

Comment: Thanks. But that is not my meaning. It is when I doubleClick `product.name`, `input` will appear. And then, I click then `<html>` (not this input) `product.name` will be save and `input` disappear.

Comment: @JeskTop Well you can put you action handler where ever  you want. i dont know you html =D

Comment: I add a picture to show the behavior process. It will be more clear.

Comment: Does it mean your `showOrHide` action is not triggered when you click anywhere after `product.name` editing is fished?

Comment: @JeskTop You need to wrap your content with some span and add an action handler to it. <div class="container" {{action 'showOrHide'}}>