# Using bind, apply or call in JavaScript Example

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dynamically creating a table row full of checkboxes using JavaScript in the function `populateParameterTr(parameters)`.  In this function, I set an event handler such that when the checkbox is made active, a hidden input field is created  in the `toggleHidden` function.

What I'm having trouble with is trying to call `toggleHidden` to create these hidden input elements after the checkbox is created, ie not in the event handler.  Reason being: I want these hidden input fields when the checkboxes are loaded for the first time.  From my understanding calling `toggleHidden()` results in `this` pointing to the global scope.

I've had a look at `bind`,`call` and `apply` to see if this will help like below:

```
toggleHidden(display, parameterContainer).bind(checkbox);
```

Can someone advise me if this can be done.  I'm looking at this example as an exercise to get my head around using these methods.

Code:

```
var populateParameterTr = function(parameters) {
   var checkboxes = $('<td></td>');

   for (var i in parameters) {
     var display = parameters[i].display;
     var checkbox = $('<input>').attr({
       //...
     });

     var parameterContainer = $('<div></div>').addClass('parameter').append(checkbox);

     checkboxes.append(parameterContainer);

     toggleHidden(display, parameterContainer).bind(checkbox); 

     checkbox.on('change', toggleHidden(display, parameterContainer));

    }
}

var toggleHidden = function(display, tableDivide) {
   return function() {
     if (this.checked) {
       var hidden = $('<input>').attr({
         //......
       });
       hidden.appendTo(tableDivide);
     } else {
       $(this).siblings("input[type='hidden']").remove();
     }
   };
};
```

Comment: Note that `bind` doesn't actually alter the original function - it instead returns a new function with the `this` value bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.call` and `.apply` directly executes the function with first `param` is `thisArg`, the difference between them is `.call` accepts `parme` like `.call(thisArg, param1, param2....)` , but `.apply` accepts like `.apply(thisArg, [param1, param2....])`.

`.bind` returns a new `Function`, when it executes, it use the first param when you call `.bind` as `thisArg`, and if you gives other param, it'll put it directly to the origin function for you, e.g:

```
var func = function(param1, param2) {
  console.log(param1, param2);
};
var bindFunc = func.bind(null, 1);

bindFunc(2);  // log 1, 2 now
```

Take above knowledge to examine the code you post:

```
toggleHidden(display, parameterContainer).bind(checkbox);
```

It Seems you want to call it, and the `this` is reference to that `checkbox`, so you can write:

```
toggleHidden.call(checkbox, display, parameterContainer);
// or 
toggleHidden.apply(checkbox, [display, parameterContainer]);
```

Then this part:

```
checkbox.on('change', toggleHidden(display, parameterContainer));
```

Here you want to call `toggleHidden` when `checkbox` change, as you're listen to checkbox's change event, and the input param should be pre-defined, you can write

```
checkbox.on('change', toggleHidden.bind(checkbox, display, parameterContainer));
```

You can get more info from [js call() & apply() vs bind()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/js-call-apply-vs-bind), [mdn-function-bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), [mdn-function-call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).