# How to pass object's method as a parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, parameter-passing

Can't figure out how to pass object's method as a parameter properly.

Here is my code:

```
var MyTest = function (p1) {
  this.p1 = p1;
};
MyTest.prototype.getParam = function () {
  return this.p1;
};

function doAction(getParamCallback) {
  console.log(getParamCallback());
}

var mt = new MyTest(123);
console.log(mt.getParam()); // 123
doAction(mt.getParam);      // undefined
```

The only way to pass a method correctly I have found is to pass both object and method and use call():

```
function doAction2(obj, getParamCallback) {
  console.log(getParamCallback.call(obj));
}
doAction2(mt, mt.getParam);    // 123
```

Is there any way that requires only method to be passed, not both method and object?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> You need to pass the `this` context as well. In provided example, methos is being called in the context of `window`, and `window` does not have property `p1`
>
> Use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to pass the context. `bind` returns a function that when later executed will have the correct context set for calling the original function. This way you can maintain context in async callbacks, and events.[[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/js-call-apply-vs-bind)]

Try this:

```js
var MyTest = function(p1) {
  this.p1 = p1;
};
MyTest.prototype.getParam = function() {
  return this.p1;
};

function doAction(getParamCallback) {
  alert(getParamCallback());
}

var mt = new MyTest(123);

doAction(mt.getParam.bind(mt));
```

Comment: Thanks Rayon! This works perfectly in Google Apps Script as well!