# Are function-arguments not necessarily objects?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm learning functional programming and node.js, and I came across this odd problem when using `Function.prototype.apply` and `.bind`.

```
function Spy(target, method) {
    var obj = {count: 0};
    var original = target[method]
    target[method] = function (){//no specified arguments
        obj.count++
        original.apply(this, arguments)//only arguments property passed
    }
    return obj;
}
module.exports = Spy
```

This code works, it successfully spies on `target.method`.

---

```
//same code here
    target[method] = function (args){//args specified
        obj.count++
        original.apply(this, args)//and passed here
    }
//same code here
```

This code, however, does not. It gives an error message: `TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object`.

---

And then the biggest surprise is, this method works perfectly fine.

```
//same code here
    target[method] = function (args){
        obj.count++
        original.bind(this, args)
    }
//same code here
```

So why exactly do I get this error? Is it because function arguments are not necessarily objects? Or is it because apply has a stricter description than bind?

Comment: Well, yes, [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) have very different descriptions. `apply` takes an array or an [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) as its second parameter - if you don't pass one, it complains.

Comment: Very unclear. First, the works/doesn't work code fragments are identical (unless I'm missing something). Second, `bind` doesn't invoke the function, so it's hard to believe that "works".

Comment: @Amit sorry, I'm going to edit so it's more apparent.

Comment: It seems like your're [confusing `apply` with `call`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1986896/1048572)

Comment: …and regarding `bind`, [it just does something completely different](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15455009/1048572).

Comment: `arguments` is an array (-ish) containing all arguments. In `function (args)`, `args` is just the name of the first parameter.

Comment: what about `original(args);`?

Comment: @Bergi I'm not confusing `apply` with `call`. I need to call the function with more than one arguments. I tried with `bind` as an "experiment" basically. And it surprisingly worked, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: @AttilaHerbert: If you need multiple arguments, then why do you only pass the single parameter `args`? And no, `bind` doesn't work at all, since it's not calling the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this version:

```js
target[method] = function (args){//args specified
        obj.count++
        original.apply(this, args)//and passed here
    }
```

Here you are not taking all the arguments but just one, named `args`. Since `apply` expects an array like object you cannot use `args` since it is only the first argument passed to the original target.

You can change it to:

```js
target[method] = function (arg){   //only one argument specified
        obj.count++
        original.apply(this,[arg]) //one argument passed here
}
```

Now it works, but you can only spy on one argument functions. Using `call` would be better since you only have one extra argument:

```js
target[method] = function (arg){ //only one argument specified
        obj.count++
        original.call(this,arg)  //one argument passed here
}
```

Now `bind` is a totally different animal. It [partial applies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) functions, thus return functions. Imagine you need to send a callback that takes no arguments but calls a function with some arguments you have when making it. You see code like:

```js
var self = this;
return function() {
  self.method(a, b);
}
```

Well. `bind` does this for you:

```js
return this.method.bind(this, a, b);
```

When calling either of these returned functions the same happens. The method `method` is called with the arguments `a` and `b`. So calling `bind` on a function returns a partial applied version of that function and does not call it like `call` or `apply` does.

Comment: Bind does not curry. If at all, it does partial application, but not even that is its main purpose.

Comment: @Bergi You're right partial application is a better term for eager languages, but I think you are wrong about the "main" purpose of `bind` as it is exactly what it does in a `call` context.

Answer (score 1):

`bind` is called the same way as `call` is, even though they do very different things.

If you really wanted to use `bind` in this way. You could use the spread operator (ES2015) to expand the arguments 'array' to individual arguments:

```
original.bind(null, ...args);
```

That will bind the `original` function with the array values as individual arguments.

Comment: I have no idea why you bother to use slice when you already have spread operator. Wet monkeys.

Comment: @Sylwester This is true, I completely forgot that you can use the spread operator on arrays and array-like objects as well. Removed the conversion before use.