# Iterating parameters for a function within a loop

Tags: javascript

JS Nooblord here, to give some context I have recently created my first JQuery based image slider to which I'm currently trying to generate a list of control buttons dynamically when the page loads.

I have succeeded thus far in creating the buttons but when it comes to writing the onclick function I'm having issues calling another function (with a parameter) inside a for loop.

I suck at explaining things but here is the code;

```
function addControls(){
    var x = document.getElementById('slider').childElementCount; 
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        var ul = document.getElementById('slider-control');
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var btn = document.createElement("Button");

        btn.onclick = function() { 
            goto(i); 
        };

        btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i + 1));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        li.appendChild(btn);
    }
}

function goto(index){
    alert(index);
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g8qeq29e/3/) preview.

What I expect is for each button to call the goto function with their respective position in the loop however every generated button with the onclick function uses the last index from the loop (4).

My initial thoughts are that the buttons are being rendered after the loops are finished and not within each iteration of the loop? also if anyone has any tips and alternatives for what I'm doing I would greatly appreciate that.

Thanks,

-Dodd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented on [Mikelis Baltruks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233197/mikelis-baltruks), you will have to use `.bind`.

You can use

```
goto.bind(null, i+1)
```

to map only index to it. If you wish to get the button as well, you can use

```
goto.bind(btn, i+1)
```

[Sample JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/g8qeq29e/5/)

#### Bind

`.bind`  is used to change the context of a function. Its syntax is

```
functionName.bind(context, argumentList);
```

This will create a reference of function with a newly binded context.

You can also use `.apply` for this task. Difference is, apply expects arguments as array and bind expect a comma separated list.

**Note:** both this function will just register events and not call it.

#### Reference

- [.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)
- [.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/apply)
- [call() & apply() vs bind()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/javascript-call-apply-vs-bind)

Comment: Still wrapping my head about the syntax but .bind works a dream, thanks

Comment: @ChrisDodd I have tried to explain the syntax. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a closure in the loop, this should work:

```
var x = document.getElementById('slider').childElementCount;
 for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  (function (i) {
   var ul = document.getElementById('slider-control');
   var li = document.createElement("li");
   var btn = document.createElement("Button");
   btn.onclick = function() {
    goto(i);
   };
   btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i + 1));
   ul.appendChild(li);
   li.appendChild(btn);
  })(i);
}


function goto(index) {
  alert(index);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g8qeq29e/6/

Or with ES6 `let` keyword;

```
function addControls(){
    var x = document.getElementById('slider').childElementCount;

    for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {//change var to let here

        var ul = document.getElementById('slider-control');
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var btn = document.createElement("Button");

        btn.onclick = function() { 
            goto(i); 
        };

        btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i + 1));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        li.appendChild(btn);
    }
}

function goto(index){
    alert(index);
}
```

Comment: a little over the top when `btn.onclick = goto.bind(null, i);` fixes the issues just as easily - not sure why the other guy deleted his answer :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Why? `bind` does the same thing in the core. This shows better what is happening I think.

Comment: @Mikey - your way is closer to the way I would do it, I was commenting because I was surprised by how simple it could be, and that the answer was then deleted!!!

Comment: @JaromandaX, there is even a better way in ES6. Will post also that answer.

Comment: I seem to recall a bug in let in a for loop like that, however, as it's an ES2015+ answer, it's probably not a problem :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Strange it got deleted. It is fine now! Should be allright

Comment: I saw it for a second!! it's still in the edit history :p

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the reference to `i`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    var btn = document.createElement("Button");
    btn.onclick = function() { 
        goto(i);
        // any variable reference will use the latest value
        // so when `onclick` is actually run, the loop will have continued on to completion, with i == 4
    };
}
```

You need a separate variable to reference for each onclick handler. You can do this by creating a closure:

```
function makeOnclick(i) {
  // `i` is now a completely separate "variable",
  // so it will not be updated while the loop continues running
  return function() { goto(i); };
}

for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    var btn = document.createElement("Button");
    btn.onclick = makeOnclick(i);
}
```

This can be done any number of ways, as others have shown. But this should explain *why* it's happening. Please ask any questions.