# ES6 class calling a method within a class with bind vs call?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have a class written in ES6 and I have a directive "action" which needs to access a controller value called "selected".  This controller value "selected" is updated by another directive "grid". ( 2 way binding)

I need to pass "selected" value from the controller that has been updated by Directive "grid" to Directive "actions" on-select . I have tried to pass by doing a "bind" but i get an type error as "cannot read actionHandler of undefined"

I am not sure what is the best way to handle this , such that when the "selected" value has been updated by the "grid" directive, the actionEvent is triggered with the updated value from the controller. The directives are working correctly and i am able to see that it breaks on breakpoints.

Here is what i have in HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-9">          
   <action options="ctrl.Actions" on-select="ctrl.actionEvent">
   </action>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <grid config="ctrl.gridOptions" data="ctrl.data" selected="ctrl.selected"></grid>
 </div>
```

In the Controller,

```
 class CheckC {
   constructor($scope) {
    this.$scope = $scope;       
    this.selected = this.$scope.selected;
  }

actionEvent() {
    this.actionHandler.bind(this);
}

actionHandler(item, event) {
    let selection;
    let model = this.selected;
    if(model) {
        item.id = 1;
    }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Try to log `this` inside `actionEvent` function, what it will show?

Comment: _"The directives are working correctly"_ But not as they should. `on-select` should expect an expression like `ctrl.actionEvent()`. That would also solve your problem.

Comment: Re-assign the bound methods to the class instance in your constructor: `this.actionHandler = this.actionHandler.bind(this)`. Just calling `this.actionHandler.bind(this)` in `actionEvent` does not invoke the method, simply creates a new function that is discarded when `actionEvent` exits as the bound method is not referenced by anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, don't be confused between `.bind()` and `.call()`.

- First returns a new function instance, that can be called later, but with preserved `this`.
- Second calls function immediately, but modifies context of `this` *only* for this call.

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/javascript-call-apply-vs-bind) for more information

You are passing a reference to `actionEvent` method. At the moment of call, the reference to original controller object is already lost.

To preserve the reference, you need to save it first in constructor

```
class CheckC {
  constructor($scope) {
    this.$scope = $scope;       
    this.selected = this.$scope.selected;
    //bind method here
    this.actionEvent = this.actionEvent.bind(this);
  }

  actionEvent(item, event) {
    // this here will be always contain a referene to class instance
    this.actionHandler(item, event);
  }

  actionHandler(item, event) {
    let selection;
    let model = this.selected;
    if(model) {
      item.id = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Also in your code `actionEvent` method seems redundant. Consider to recfactor code and pass `actionHandler` directly. (Bu don't forget to update `.bind()` call, it should bind `actionHandler` after).