# What "call" function do in js?

Tags: javascript

I saw code:

```
Host.call(this, logger, config);
```

`Host` is a function name with no parent.
`call` seems not defined in the function's definition.

Is `call` a special function? As `call` is a highly used word, it seems not easy to search "JS call" for any useful explanation.

Comment: Well.. It calls function. (`Host` in your example)

Comment: This should help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call. In simple words, it will change the context of function and call it. Another reference link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/javascript-call-apply-vs-bind

Comment: asked and answered countless times on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.call()` sets `this` within `Host` function to `this` passed at first parameter where `logger`, `config` are additional parameters passed to `Host` function

```js
function Host(a, b) {
  // `this` : `obj`
  console.log("in Host", this, a, b);
  this.a = a;       
  this.b = b;
}

var obj = {};

Host.call(obj, 1, 2);

console.log(obj.a, obj.b); // set at `obj` : `this` at call to `Host`
```

Answer (score 1):

> All functions have two built-in methods that allow the programmer to supply arguments *and* `this` variable also: `call` and `apply`.

So in your question, the `Host` method is being called with the`logger` and `config` arguments, but you're also passing in a reference to whatever is currently `this`.