# Why is JavaScript bind() necessary?

Tags: javascript, this, bind

The problem in example 1 is 'this' referring to the global name instead of the myName object.

I understand the use of bind() in setting the value of this to a specific object, so it solves the problem in example 1, but why does this problem occur in the first place? Is it just the way Javascript was created?

I'm also wondering why example 3 solves the issue and the difference between example 2 and 3.

```js
this.name = "John"

var myName = {
  name: "Tom",
  getName: function() {
    return this.name
  }
}

var storeMyName = myName.getName; // example 1
var storeMyName2 = myName.getName.bind(myName); // example 2
var storeMyName3 = myName.getName(); // example 3

console.log("example 1: " + storeMyName()); // doesn't work
console.log("example 2: " + storeMyName2()); // works
console.log("example 3: " + storeMyName3); // works
```

Comment: *"Is it just the way Javascript was created?"* I guess yes. The value of `this` is determined dynamically, unless it is a bound or an arrow function. Not sure what else you want to know expect [learning about how `this` works](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript call() & apply() vs bind()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/javascript-call-apply-vs-bind)

Comment: *"I'm also wondering why example 3 solves the issue"* `storeMyName` and `storeMyName2` contain *functions* whereas `storeMyName3` contains the *result* of *calling* `myName.getName()`. Big difference. I made this comparison between ways of calling a function and `.bind`: https://twitter.com/fkling42/status/736228742008176640 . Maybe it helps somehow.

Comment: https://medium.com/@dave_lunny/bind-for-dummies-5d1a750725b8#.liz1lnoo1

Comment: This is a great read. It has cleared up everything about `this` in JS for me: https://rainsoft.io/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/

Comment: Because JS is confusing as fuck. Try to run the function, if it runs without bind great, otherwise bind it and it will work. That's what I do, works every time.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

> Why is JavaScript bind() necessary?

The value of `this` is determined by *how* a function is *called*. If it is *you* who calls the function then there is usually no need to use `.bind`, since you have control over how to call the function, and therefore its `this` value.

However, often it is *not* you who calls the function. Functions are passed to other functions as callbacks and event handlers. They are called by *other* code and you have no control over *how* the function is called, and therefore cannot control what `this` will refer to.

If your function requires `this` to be set to a specific value and you are not the one calling the function, you need to `.bind` the function to a specific `this` value.

In other words: `.bind` allows you to set the value of `this` without calling the function *now*.

Here is comparison of referring to/calling functions:

```
                    +-------------------+-------------------+
                    |                   |                   |
                    |      time of      |       time of     |
                    |function execution |    this binding   |
                    |                   |                   |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|                   |                   |                   |
|  function object  |      future       |      future       |
|         f         |                   |                   |
|                   |                   |                   |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|                   |                   |                   |
|   function call   |       now         |        now        |
|        f()        |                   |                   |
|                   |                   |                   |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|                   |                   |                   |
|     f.call()      |       now         |        now        |
|     f.apply()     |                   |                   |
|                   |                   |                   |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|                   |                   |                   |
|     f.bind()      |      future       |        now        |
|                   |                   |                   |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

> I'm also wondering why example 3 solves the issue and the difference between example 2 and 3.

Example 1/2 and 3 couldn't be more different. `storeMyName` and `storeMyName2` contain *functions*, which are called in the future, whereas `storeMyName3` contains the result of calling `myName.getName()` *at that moment*.

---

Further reading material:

- [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/218196)
- [MDN - this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [YDKS - this & Object Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/93abe1810e84253ed46535120a3c62a8e309edda/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes)
- [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and the resources. I'm new to javascript and you made the answer very obvious for me. So call()/apply() is the same as example 3, except used when the getName() method is separate from the object?

Comment: Basically yes. If a function is a property of an object, then calling the function as `myName.getName()` will implicitly set `this` to `myName`. It's equivalent to `myName.getName.call(myName)`.

Answer (score 6):

From [mdn wed docs on Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind),

> The `bind()` method of `Function` instances creates a new function that, when called, calls this function with its `this` keyword set to the provided value, and a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

So, when you execute `var storeMyName = myName.getName;` the first time, it takes the global `name` ( `this.name = "John"` ).

When you use `bind()` function, it starts referring to the name defined in the current closure ( `myName` in this case ) and hence prints `Tom`.

Third time, since the function is called right away, its scope is within its own local object and thus prints the value in the closure `Tom`.

Answer (score 4):

An analogy i like, which i have never seen anywhere:
Let say you have a foo object with a `bar` function.
When you are binding the bar function to another variable (or passing it as a function parameter, which is more common case with callbacks), you are not binding/passing the function with his enclosing object but only the  "nude" function.
Hence with the "nude" function, `this` means the global object.

A small demo

```
var foo = "global foo"; //foo set on the global object
var a = {foo : "object foo", bar : function(){return this.foo;}};
var bound = a.bar;
console.log(bound());//returns "global foo", not "object foo"
```

`bound` just point to the `function(){return this.foo;}`

Comment: Finally someone explained the reason!. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Bind is the mechanism by which you can change the context(here your default context is global) of execution.

Based on your example -

```
var storeMyName = myName.getName;
```

From above line is you are executing `storeMyName` function in global context, so for this execution `this.name` will be top line(i.e. global one / "John").

```
var storeMyName2 = myName.getName.bind(myName);
```

For above line you are **Explicitly**  changing the context of execution for `storeMyName2` function(by saying that i don't want to execute this function as global function i want to execute this function in context of `myName` object, so in this case `this.name` will be "Tom")

```
var storeMyName3 = myName.getName(); // example 3
```

And for this above line you are just executing function on `myName` object context, more importantly you are not executing the `storeMyName3` and that's why its context is not global one.