# JavaScript Objects Rules

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am currently working on javascript Function and Objects but there is a little bit confusion.

I have created an object and called its method in the window like 
`obj.something();`, it gives me result but when I write same code in console like `console.log(obj.something());`, it gives me `undefined` in the console

So, my question is obviously why & how?

```js
var obj ={
    value: 1,
    increment: function () {
        this.value += 1
        // return this
    },

    add: function (v) {
        this.value += v
        // return this
    },

    shout: function () {
        console.log(this.value);
        // return this
    }
};
obj.shout();
console.log(obj.shout());
```

Comment: `undefined` is the default return value from a function without `return`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41391816/4590521

Answer (score 3):

`undefined` is the default return value from a function without `return`.

From MDN docs of [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return):

> When a `return` statement is called in a function, the execution of this function is stopped. If specified, a given value is returned to the function caller. If the expression is omitted, `undefined` is returned instead.

Comment: that's my point why it give undefined in console.log(obj.shout()) although it gives a result while writing the code obj.shout(); only kindly create difference between them so i will understand easily.

Comment: the point is, a function returns always something, but it is not seen. you see it only if you process the return value from the function, like `console.log` or other use, but not if you just call the function. it is the same if you call `Math.sin(90)`without assigning the result to a value. it became calculated but the result is gone.

Answer (score 1):

```
You hava to return value from function ,Like this

    var obj ={
    value: 1,
    increment: function () {
        this.value += 1
        // return this
    },

    add: function (v) {
        this.value += v
        // return this
    },

    shout: function () {
         return this;
    }
   };
   obj.shout();
   console.log(obj.shout());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the display of "undefined" **without adding a "return"** by using the **.call()** instead of using **()** in a function.

```js
var obj ={
    value: 1,
    increment: function () {
        this.value += 1
        // return this
    },

    add: function (v) {
        this.value += v
        // return this
    },

    shout: function () {
        console.info("Line-14");
        console.log(this.value);
        console.info("Line-16");
         //return;
    }
};
var objectShootResult = obj.shout;
console.info("Line-21");
objectShootResult.call(obj);
console.info("Line-22");
```