# RxJS.fromCallback() doesn't work for MySqlJs query method

Tags: javascript, mysql, rxjs

```
 var query = Rx.Observable.fromCallback(dbConnection.query);
 var obs = query('select * from mytable where id = ?', ['389']);
 obs.subscribe(
     function(e) = {}
 );
```

This code is giving me TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeCast' of undefined.

The documentation for MySqlJs query method looks like this:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `author` = ?', ['David'], function (error, results, fields)
```

When I log query it returns [Function]. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `query` function will be passed to `fromCallback`, but when it's called it will not be bound to `dbConnection`.

You should do something like this:

```js
Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(dbConnection.query.bind(dbConnection));
```

Also, you probably want [`fromNodeCallback`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromnodecallback.md).

Comment: This appears to work, I am using Node though. What does bind() do and why fromNodeCallback() it looks the same to me. Sorry I'm a Java developer so I'm struggling with the language a bit.

Comment: Node callbacks follow the pattern of having an error as the first parameter and `fromNodeCallback` takes that into account. And `bind` is needed because `this` is weird in JS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41391426/6680611

Comment: thanks for that! That makes a lot of sense. Coming from Java this is super clear, but the dynamicness of JS makes for weird stuff like this. Thank you!