# How to access this.setstate in onShouldStartLoadWithRequest() of a WebView in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, this, pass-by-reference

I'm really struggling to understand how to read and set this.state inside of functions called by WebView when doing specific operations. My end goal is to:

- Show a activity indicator when the user clicks a link inside the webview
- Perform certain actions based on the URL the user is clicking on

I'm very new to React, but from what I've learned, I should use `() => function` to bind `this` from the main object to be accessible inside the function.

This works on `onLoad={(e) => this._loading('onLoad Complete')}` and I can update the state when the page loaded the first time.

If I use `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={this._onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}` I can see that it works and my **console.warn()** is shown on screen. **this.state** is of course not available.

However if I change it to `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={() => this._onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}` the function doesn't seem to be executed at all, and neither this.state (commented in the code below) or console.warn() is run.

Any help is appreciated!

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import {Text,View,WebView} from 'react-native';

class Question extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
            debug: 'Debug header'
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1, marginTop:20}}>
                <Text style={{backgroundColor: '#f9f', padding: 5}}>{this.state.debug}</Text>
                <WebView
                    source={{uri: 'http://stackoverflow.com/'}}
                    renderLoading={this._renderLoading}
                    startInLoadingState={true}
                    javaScriptEnabled={true}
                    onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={this._onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
                    onNavigationStateChange = {this._onShouldStartLoadWithRequest} 
                    onLoad={(e) => this._loading('onLoad Complete')}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }

    _loading(text) {
        this.setState({debug: text});
    }

    _renderLoading() {
        return (
            <Text style={{backgroundColor: '#ff0', padding: 5}}>_renderLoading</Text>
        )
    }

    _onShouldStartLoadWithRequest(e) {
        // If I call this with this._onShouldStartLoadWithRequest in the WebView props, I get "this.setState is not a function"
        // But if I call it with () => this._onShouldStartLoadWithRequest it's not executed at all,
        // and console.warn() isn't run
        //this.setState({debug: e.url});
        console.warn(e.url);
        return true;
    }

}



module.exports = Question;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access correct this (class context) inside `_onShouldStartLoadWithRequest`, you need to `bind` it with class context, after binding whenever this method will get called `this` keyword inside it will point to react class.

Like this:

```
onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={this._onShouldStartLoadWithRequest.bind(this)}
```

or use `arrow function` like this:

```
onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={this._onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}

_onShouldStartLoadWithRequest = (e) => {...}
```

Or like this:

```
onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={(e) => this._onShouldStartLoadWithRequest(e)}
```

Check this answer for more details: [Why is JavaScript bind() necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391288/why-is-javascript-bind-necessary)

Comment: Great, it worked regarding the this.state binding, however I get **undefined is not an object (evaluating ’e.url’)**. The function is `_onShouldStartLoadWithRequest(e)` and should contain e.url, which it did when I didn't bind.

Comment: check the updated answer, in case of arrow function you need to pass the `e`, try now. btw first way should work when u use `.bind(this)`.

Comment: For some reason the first one works perfectly, the second one returns undefined for e.url. Thank you very much!