# TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I am very new to react and I am having issues when it comes to passing data from one method to another method. 
Here is my react syntax:

```
var url = "https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1"
class App extends React.Component{
  info(val){
  console.log(val)
  }

request(){
  axios.get(url)
  .then(function (response) {
      this.info(response)
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  }

render() {
    return(

    <div>
        <h1>axios</h1>
      {this.request()}
      </div>

    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("target"))
```

My goal is to pass the response data from `request` method to `info` method. However, I am getting error saying that `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined"`
Can you help me identify what I am missing?

Comment: Binding issue, Check the duplicate question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very Common issue and so many answers available for the same, so addition answer as community wiki.

It's a binding issue, you need to bind `this` with callback.

Use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
.then( (response) => {
```

For more details Check this answer: [Why is JavaScript bind() necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391288/why-is-javascript-bind-necessary)