# Why function works without "this" binding?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using React and Redux. I have a question. I know when I need "this" in a function I should `bind` it. But without binding my code works. Why ?
Function :

```
onSubmit() {
    this.props.dispatch({type: 'ADD_TO_LIST', payload: this.state.inputValue});
}
```

And this is my render input :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Text ..." onChange={(e) => {
this.setState({inputValue: e.target.value})}} onKeyDown={(e) => {
if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    this.onSubmit()
}
}}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have idea about "when binding is required", but you missed one thing, "calling function will have the this (object by which it was called)". The value of `this` is determined by how a function is called.

Here:

```
this.onSubmit()
```

You are calling submit with `this` (class instance), so `this` (inside submit) will refer to class instance.

Check these references:

[MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

[Why is JavaScript bind() necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391288/why-is-javascript-bind-necessary)

Answer (score 0):

Because you used an arrow function to call it, it's not the event handler itself. The arrow function is already bound correctly.

Answer (score 0):

While `function` is binding (it changes `this`), ES6 arrow functions are [non-binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). An example:

```
this.a = 1;

obj = {
  a: 2,
  bfunction: function() { return this.a; },
  barrow: () => { return this.a; },
}

console.log(obj.bfunction()) // 2
console.log(obj.barrow()) // 1
```