# In React, how to call multiple functions with their own arguments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, react-props

I want to call two functions passes via props on click. Note that both of them need arguments of their own. After a bit of searching on Stack Overflow, I found this solution:

```
onclick={()=>{ f1(); f2() }}
```

So I implemented mine as follows:

```
onClick={() => {f1(arg); f2.bind(this, arg)}}
```

But the second function never gets called. Can anyone please explain why this isn't working? I'm assuming its some binding issue?

f1 is in the parent component:

```
f1(arg, event)
{
        event.preventDefault();
        // so on...
}
```

f2 is also in the parent argument as follows:

```
f2(arg)
{
     // do something with the argument 
}
```

They are getting passed to the child component

```
 render()
    {
            const { f2, arg, f1 } = this.props;
    
            return(
                <button onClick={() => {f2(arg); f1.call(this, arg)}}>
)
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second function isn't working, because you not actually calling function using **bind**, you just binding scope for future function calls. If you want to call function with specified scope, use **call** or **apply**

More about them:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15455043/5709697

**EDIT**

For your case you can call second function like so:

```
onClick={(e) => {f1(e); f2.call(this, e)}}
```

Link to sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/509o1lxjp

Comment: How will I call the function here after binding it?

Comment: I also need to pass argument to f2. So will that be implemented like f2.call(this,e,arg) ?

Comment: Gives 'TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function'. Why do we have to pass event when we've already passed this?

Comment: Actually, as @Mayank Shukla said, there are no need to call second function using call(or maybe the need exist, depends on situation). I've provided sandbox, where that funtionality, which you asking for works. Maybe you can edit with your code, and show us, what's going on?

Comment: My answer is updated. Can you please share the sandbox?

Comment: It works! THANK YOU. Can you please explain why it works though? Why do we need to pass event when we have already bounded it to 'this'?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
 onClick={(arg)=>{ this.f1(arg); this.f2(this, arg) }}
```

Or make a separate function call as below.

```
onClick={(arg)=>{ this.f1(arg) }}

f1(values){
this.f2(values);
}
```

Comment: what if first one is asynchronous ..i want the second one to be executed only after the first one gets successfully completed

Answer (score 1):

You can call both methods as

```
onClick={() =>{ this.f1(arg);this.f2(arg)}}
```

Comment: binding of those methods are not required, because you are normally calling them :)

Comment: what if first one is asynchronous ..i want the second one to be executed only after the first one gets successfully completed

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not calling the second method just creating it using bind.

When you used `() => {}` with onClik, context will be maintained by [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), you don't need to bind those two functions after that.

Write it like this:

```
onClick={(e) => {
   this.f1(e, arg1, arg2, arg3);     // use f1, if function is defined outside of class
   this.f2(e, arg2)
}}

f1 (e, arg1, arg2, arg3) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(arg1, arg2, arg3)
}

f2 (e, arg2) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(arg2)
}
```

Check [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind): `The bind() method creates a new function.`

---

Check these answers for more details about binding:

[Use of the JavaScript 'bind' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

[Why is JavaScript bind() necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391288/why-is-javascript-bind-necessary)

Comment: The second function has got the event property so I need to pass this as an argument. Doing what you suggested gave me the error: '×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined'

Comment: that means you forgot to pass the event object to functions, check the updated answer.

Comment: if you don't want to use the event in any function then don't pass as an argument, lets say you want only in 2nd function, then remove from 1st function, like this: `this.f1(arg1, arg2, arg3); ` and remove from function argument also.

Comment: TypeError: _this2.f1 is not a function

Comment: @eren555 can you show the full code, where you have defined the f1 and f2 and the element on which you are using the click handler?