# Why javascript call method fails to execute on array prototype method

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, callback, call

I am playing with JS features to improve my understanding of the language.

In below example, I was trying to use `call` method to initiate Array function on given array object. I know alternatives to get the job done; however, I am curious why the code I have written does not work?.

Thank you!

**Code**

```js
const f_timeit = (f) => {
  return function(...args) {
    util.p(`Entering function ${f.name}`);
    const start_time = Date.now();
    try {
      return f(...args);
    } finally {
      util.p(`Exiting ${f.name} after ${Date.now() - start_time}ms`);
    }
  }
};

const rarr = [...Array(10000000)].map(e => ~~(Math.random() * 20));

// following works
console.log(f_timeit((arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
})(rarr));

// following fails
util.p(f_timeit(Array.prototype.reduce.call)(rarr, (acc, val) => acc + val, 0));
```

**Error:**

```bash
        return f(...args);
               ^
TypeError: f is not a function
```

Comment: The `call` method is not bound to the `reduce` function. You may as well have used `f_timeit(Function.prototype.call)`, same thing. The error message is very misleading btw, it's not that `f` is not a function but rather that `call` was invoked on something that is not a function.

Comment: "*I know alternatives to get the job done*" - what solutions do you have in mind?

Comment: @Bergi I meant the arrow function solution I put above. Btw, what would be arguments of that call method if I call as you suggested; how i will specify to call Array.prototype.reduce?

Comment: You can use [`call.bind(reduce)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Another (better) solution is to use `f.apply(this, args)` in `f_timeit`, then `f_timeit(Array.prototype.reduce).call(rarr, …, 0)`.

Comment: This has issue still `f_timeit(Array.prototype.reduce).call(rarr, (acc, val) => acc + val, 0)`

Comment: Did you change `f_timeit` when you tried that?

Comment: My bad, I missed that part. It works. Please post as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is a bit misleading, it's not that "`f` is not a function" but rather that `f` is the `Function.prototype.call` method that was invoked on something that is not a function - in particular `undefined`. This is due to [how the `this` argument works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1048572), and in particular because [accessing methods on an object does not automatically bind them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41391288/1048572).

So various ways to achieve what you want are

```
f_timeit(() => rarr.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0))()
f_timeit((ctx) => ctx.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0))(rarr)
f_timeit((ctx, reducer) => ctx.reduce(reducer, 0))(rarr, (acc, val) => acc + val)
f_timeit((ctx, reducer, init) => ctx.reduce(reducer, init))(rarr, (acc, val) => acc + val, 0)
f_timeit((ctx, ...args) => ctx.reduce(...args))(rarr, (acc, val) => acc + val, 0)
f_timeit((ctx, ...args) => Array.prototype.reduce.apply(ctx, args))(rarr, (acc, val) => acc + val, 0)
f_timeit((ctx, ...args) => Array.prototype.reduce.call(ctx, ...args))(rarr, (acc, val) => acc + val, 0)
f_timeit((...args) => Array.prototype.reduce.call(...args))(rarr, (acc, val) => acc + val, 0)
// f_timeit(Array.prototype.reduce.call)(rarr, (acc, val) => acc + val, 0) - no!
f_timeit(Array.prototype.reduce.call.bind(Array.prototype.reduce))(rarr, (acc, val) => acc + val, 0) // yes!
f_timeit(Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.reduce))(rarr, (acc, val) => acc + val, 0)
```

However, I would generally recommend that you change `f_timeit` to respect the `this` value passed when the returned function is called:

```
const f_timeit = (f) => {
  return function(...args) {
    util.p(`Entering function ${f.name}`);
    const start_time = Date.now();
    try {
      return f.call(this, ...args);
//                  ^^^^
      return f.apply(this, args); // or equivalently
    } finally {
      util.p(`Exiting ${f.name} after ${Date.now() - start_time}ms`);
    }
  }
};
```

That way, you can use

```
f_timeit(Array.prototype.reduce).call(rarr, (acc, val) => acc + val, 0)
```