# Call function on app load and bind navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I can't for the love of god find anything on this, or I just don't know exactly what to search for. I'm new to React and React Native and I need help with my RN project. What I'm trying to do is call a function `auto_login()` in my component `MainLogic`. The function looks as follows and is placed in the `module.exports`:

```
auto_login: function(navigator){
    if(GLOBALS.LOGGED_IN != true){
      Keychain
      .getGenericPassword()
      .then(function(credentials){
        fetch(GLOBALS.API_URL, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
          body: "username=" + credentials.username + "&password=" + credentials.password,
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
          if(JSON.stringify(response.status).replace(new RegExp('"', 'g'), '').match("OK")){
            GLOBALS.LOGGED_IN = true;
            GLOBALS.USERNAME = credentials.username;
            GLOBALS.PASSWORD = credentials.password;

            navigator.push({
              id: 'news'
            });
          }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.warn(e);
        })
        .done();
      });
    }
  },
```

Right now I'm calling this function from

```
componentDidMount: function(){
  MainLogic.auto_login(navigator);
},
```

before the `render` function but I realise the navigator is out of context or something. I'd like some help to understand how I'd go about calling this function and binding the `navigator` properly. I'm right now getting a warning:

```
TypeError: navigator.push is not a function. (in 'navigator.push({id:'news'})', 'navigator.push' is undefined.
```

Any help in understanding this is highly appreciated!

**Edit:** I'm using React.createClass.

Comment: Try adding a constructor with a line below super(); this.auto_login = this.auto_login.bind(this);

Comment: To clarify: I'm using the React.createClass, not ES6. Do you know anything similar that can be applied to my structure?

Comment: componentWillMount: function() {
    this.auto_login = this.auto_login.bind(this);
}

Comment: @EnieJakiro Ah, I see. So I tried this, but instead used "this.auto_login = MainLogic.auto_login.bind(this);" since the function is in the MainLogic component and not in the index file. But I get the warning "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.refs')". The line throwing the error in auto_login() is "this.refs["nav"].push({id: 'news'});". Any ideas?

Comment: I think problem is that your this keyword is out of the scope. Since refs should always be defined. Are you certain of that binding? Can you try 'this.auto_login = this.auto_login.bind(this);' maybe MainLogic refer to something I'm not aware of.

Comment: I would also suggest ES6 feature arrow functions, which binds your function but you aren't using ES6.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/javascript-call-apply-vs-bind check this link, it may help at binding and calling your function in sequence, in your componentDidMount().

Comment: @EnieJakiro Wow, thanks for all the great help! Though I gotta admit I'm still a bit lost when it comes to applying the solutions from that link. To clarify what MainLogic is: "import MainLogic from './app/components/logic/main_logic.js';" (at the top of index.ios.js). I've tried "this.auto_login = this.auto_login.bind(this)" after placing the auto_login() function in index.ios.js, I still end up with the same warning. From my understanding it seems like you said that "this" is out of the scope. Is refs supposed to be defined even in componentDidMount()?

Comment: I've also tried "this.auto_login.apply(this);" and "this.auto_login.call(this);" in componentDidMount(); with no success

Comment: Shall we move to chat? I think I can help you if you send me the files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132196/discussion-between-enie-jakiro-and-johannes-nyman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to replace your navigator in **main_logic.js** file, *this* *keyword* in **auto_login** didn't point your function's context. Binding also didn't help since *this* *keyword* remained pointing the same context.

Best way I can think of is passing the context, *this* *keyword*, to main_logic.js and then instead of calling

```
this.refs['nav']
```

we'll change it into

```
paramName.refs['nav']
```

I suspect there could be better solutions, so I'm encouraging you to take a deeper look and iterate the problem as you advance in React Native and JS.