# Aurelia binding for button callback function

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I want to pass an array of objects that define buttons to a custom element, like this:

```
<my-panel header="My Title" 
  view-buttons.bind="[{icon: 'fa-plus', display: 'New', action: onNew}]">
</my-panel>
```

In my custom element, I'm displaying the buttons like this:

```
<button repeat.for="btn of viewButtons" class="btn btn-default" click.delegate="goButton(btn)">
  <i class="fa ${btn.icon} fa-fw"></i> ${btn.display}
</button>
```

The called function in my custom element's view-model is:

```
goButton(btn) {
  if (btn.action) {
    btn.action();
  }
}
```

The called function in my parent view-model is:

```
onNew() {
  window.alert("HORRAY!!!  Now why is this not working?");
  console.log("view=", this.view);  // should be 'home', but displays 'undefined'
  this.view = 'new_view';
}
```

The button displays correctly and I get the `window.alert` message which means the parent function was called.  However, it appears that the **scope/context** of the function is wrong (it's not seeing or updating the parent's `this.view`).

What am I doing wrong?  My guess is that it's related to `action: onNew` but I don't know how to fix it.  If it were a bound parameter, I think I could use `action.call="onNew"` but not in an array of objects.  Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how javascript works. To solve this you can use:

```
{icon: 'fa-plus', display: 'New', action: this.onNew.bind(this) }
```

Running example: https://gist.run/?id=cefe45c5a402c348d01d41d9cde42489

Explanation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

[Javascript call() & apply() vs bind()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/javascript-call-apply-vs-bind)

https://alexperry.io/personal/2016/04/03/How-to-use-apply-bind-and-call.html

Comment: Thanks... that worked.  Do you know if there's a way to do this from within the view's HTML markup (see original question)?

Comment: I think you'd have to inject the parent and use it as a paremeter. Something like this `click.delegate="goButton.call(parent, { btn: btn })`.