# Proper use of bind and referencing objects values in a click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the proper use of bind and the reference to past links being opened in my on click handler.

This function receives an array of 4 links. I simply want to open the correct link on click.

Links 2 and 3 work because they are bound to the window object. Links 0 and 1 will work on the first array that is passed but when a new array of links is passed to the function, when clicked, it will open the previous link and not the one that was most recently passed to the function.

I know that adding values to the window object is bad practice so I've been trying to figure out a better way to implement it while gaining a better grasp on bind,apply, and call. (If even necessary here).

Why is it that the first 4 links passed are correct but any other time links are passed, it will continue to reference and open the initial set of links?

```
links = function(linksArr) {
    var that = this;
    this.linkArray = linksArr;
    //Create an object from array in attempt to get correct link on event click
    var linkReference = linksArr.reduce(function(all,item,index){
       all[index] = item;
       console.log(all);
       return all;
    },{});
   //Does not work. Attempted use of bind
    $('.link0').on("click", function () {
        window.open(linkReference[0], '_blank');
    }.bind(linkReference));
    //Does not work. Trying to apply the proper links through the apply method
    $('.link1').on("click", function () {
        window.open(linksArr[1], '_blank');
    }.apply(null,linksArr));
    //Works
    $('.link2').on("click", function () {
        window.open(that.linkArray[2], '_blank');
    });
    //Works
    $('.link3').on("click", function () {
        window.open(that.linkArray[3], '_blank');
    });
};`
```

Comment: You don't need `bind`, `apply` or `call` here. Your code doesn't seem to be object oriented (your use of `this.linkArray` seems unnecessary, but we'd need to see the rest of the code, I suppose). If you want to know how they are used - check elsewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/javascript-call-apply-vs-bind

Answer (score 1):

`bind()` makes the element you bind with be the 'this' inside the method.  You should use 'this' as the reference, not the name you used when you bound.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind