# Access this.props in imported function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a function that sits in one of my React components that's starting to get a bit long. I've decided to keep it in a separate file to keep my component a bit tidier. The issue is that the component has to refer to `this` in order to get functions and states that are mapped to the props through Redux. Here's how I call it in my component:

```
import {myFunction} from './functions/myFunction';

handleMyFunction(event) {
    myFunction(event).bind(this)
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.handleMyFunction()
}
```

Here is the function itself in './functions/myFunction':

```
export const captureSnapshot = (event) => {
    console.log(this.props.someState)
}
```

I would have thought that bind `this` would make all the props available in the imported function but instead I get:

> Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

when I try to run the function. How can I pass "this" to the function properly?

Comment: You are trying to access and call `.bind` on the **return value** of `myFunction`. `myFunction(event)` resolves to the return value of `myFunction`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use bind in function execution

this line is wrong

`myFunction(event).bind(this)`

instead use `apply` or `call`

example `myFunction.call(this , event)` or `myFunction.apply(this , [event])`

You can learn more about the difference between 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/javascript-call-apply-vs-bind)

Also one more edit you might have this function `handleMyFunction` with incorrect `this` context as well so change it to

```
handleMyFunction = (event) => {
    myFunction.call(this , event)
}
```

Comment: I tried both of your methods and they're both giving me the exact same error message!

Comment: can you `console.log(this.props.someState)` before calling the function and check if this value exist , probably `handleMyFunction` does not have the correct `this` as well i updated the answer to use arrow function to be called with correct `this` context as well

Comment: The issue was with me having an arrow function instead of just a normal one in myFunction.js. I changed it to a normal one and it had the right context, now works. Can you update your answer to reflect that please?