# What's bind and apply mean?

Tags: javascript

[MDN bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
// same as "slice" in the previous example
var unboundSlice = Array.prototype.slice;
var slice = Function.prototype.apply.bind(unboundSlice);

// ...

slice(arguments);
```

when I write like below

```
function add(num1, num2){
     return num1 + num2;
 }
var test = Function.prototype.apply.bind(add);
var result = test([1,2])
```

It's wrong.
I don't know where I was wrong in my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript call() & apply() vs bind()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/javascript-call-apply-vs-bind)

Answer (score 1):

`Function.prototype.apply` takes more than just the `[1, 2]` argument for the argument list – it takes the `this` argument before it. [(docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) In other words, what your code is effectively doing is this:

```
function add(num1, num2){
    return num1 + num2;
}

var result = add.apply([1, 2]);
```

and what you want is this:

```
function add(num1, num2){
    return num1 + num2;
}

var result = add.apply(null, [1, 2]);
```

achievable thusly:

```js
function add(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
}

var test = Function.prototype.apply.bind(add, null);
var result = test([1, 2]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: but, why the MDN's example doesn't take the second argument as `null` rather than take the `argument` directly?

Comment: @Liuuil: Which example are you referring to?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) , right above #Polyfill

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @Liuuil: That’s because it actually wants to call `Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)`, not `Array.prototype.slice.apply(null, arguments)`. `arguments` is the “this” argument.

Answer (score 0):

**What MDN is doing**:

1. `slice` is a method of Array objects, but can be applied to array like objects, such as `arguments` which have a length and numeric string property names, to convert the object into an actual Array object instance:

   ```
   Array.prototype.slice.apply( arguments)
   ```

Note this code does NOT call `slice` with any parameter values. If any were required, they could be added as an array of values to the actual argument list of `apply`. It works because `slice` uses its `this` value (set to [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)) as the array like object, and will operate without any additional parameters.

2. `apply` is a method of function objects, and in the code above, is inherited from    Function.prototype`by the`slice` function.

---

Now break down the code in (1) above into two pieces:

```
const slice = Array.prototype.slice   // a) 
slice.apply( arguments)             // b) and c)
```

a) creates a reference to the `slice` function stored in `Array.prototype`.

b) calls `slice`'s `apply` method, inherited from `Function.prototype`, with a `this` value of `slice` *for simple reason that `apply` is being called as a method of `slice`*.

c) `apply` calls its `this` value (`slice`) with `slice`'s `this` value set to the first argument supplied to `apply`.

But notice in the broken down code the `apply` function is called with a constant `this` value - namely the `slice` function. If we bind `apply` to `slice` we can compress all the steps into a single function call:

```
const slice = Array.prototype.slice;
const boundApply = slice.apply.bind(slice);
```

making `boundApply( arguments)` equivalent to

```
 Function.prototype.apply.bind(Array.prototype.slice)(arguments)
```

While the MDN example puts this bound version of `apply` in a variable called `slice`, the resultant function's argument syntax is that of  [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). Because of this `start` and `end` parameters for `slice` can be added as the second and third arguments of the bound function.

Hence your example needs to supply an argument list suitable for `apply`, not `add`

```
function add(num1, num2){
 return num1 + num2;
}
var test = Function.prototype.apply.bind(add);
var result = test(null, [1,2])
```

The reply from @Ryan shows how to wrap this into a single function that does not require `null`.

---

**Summary**

`Function.prototype.bind` is used to create an exotic function with a specific  `this` value. Even if you save the the bound function as an object property and call it as a method of the object, the `this` value it sees is the one that was supplied to `bind`. This can be useful for, say, event handlers that use a `this` value other than `null`, `window` or the element on which the event was fired.

`Function.prototype.apply` allows you to dynamically supply the `this` value of a called function. It may be more efficient than using `bind` for a single call to an existing or anonymous function (because it does not require creating a bound function object) or may suit an application that wants to call the same function on multiple objects to be used as the function's this value.

Note that `bind` and `apply` only affect the `this` value of functions declared using the `function` keyword. You can [not bind the `this` value of arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33308121/5217142) in JavaScript.

Comment: In the b) `var slice = unboundSlice.bind( Function.prototype.apply)` do you mean `var slice = Function.prototype.apply.bind( unBoundSlice)` instead?

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. Fixed and summary answer to the question title added.

Comment: I feel dumb : (

Comment: @AwokeKnowing revisiting after 4 years convinced me to update the answer ... it had me confused as well :(-