# using 'this' in forEach() or sort()

Tags: javascript

When i try:

```
    this.rezerwacjeFilteredByseaarchInput.sort(function (a, b) {
      if (this.idSortOrder) {
        return a[0].id - b[0].id;
      }
      else {
        return b[0].id - a[0].id;
      }

    });
```

js throws: this.idSortOrder is undefined.
but when i try:

```
let idSortOrder = this.idSortOrder;
    this.rezerwacjeFilteredByseaarchInput.sort(function (a, b) {
      if (idSortOrder) {
        return a[0].id - b[0].id;
      }
      else {
        return b[0].id - a[0].id;
      }

    });
```

it works. can anybody show me how to this.idSortOrder directly in sort or foreach function?

Comment: Use an arrow function or pass this via the this parameter of forEach (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). I’d also familiarize yourself with this, Kyle Simpson’s free book explains this well (https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS). Also lookup closures and specifically lexical scoping (JS definitive 6th ed. is good!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem arises because `this`, in the callback, isn't the one you expect (it's `undefined` in strict mode, the global object in loose mode). You can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to preserve it.

Replace

```
this.rezerwacjeFilteredByseaarchInput.sort(function (a, b) {
```

with

```
this.rezerwacjeFilteredByseaarchInput.sort((a, b) => {
```

Or if you need to be compatible with old browsers and can't use transpilers like Babel, simply store `this`:

```
var nameThatObject = this;
this.rezerwacjeFilteredByseaarchInput.sort(function (a, b) {
      if (nameThatObject.idSortOrder) {
```

Comment: OP should also look at [bind, call and apply functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/javascript-call-apply-vs-bind) to change the value of `this` inside functions.

Comment: ^.. + `forEach` has its own parameter for the `this` value.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `.bind`:

```
this.rezerwacjeFilteredByseaarchInput.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (this.idSortOrder) {
    return a[0].id - b[0].id;
  }
  else {
    return b[0].id - a[0].id;
  }

}.bind(this));
```

This will bind the context your inner closer to be that of the outer one.

Answer (score 1):

> "this" inside the function doesn't point to the same object as that of "this" present outside the function,that is the reason we aren't able to access "idSortOrder" property [Look at this description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)
>   ,instead try this:

```
var self = this;
this.rezerwacjeFilteredByseaarchInput.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (self .[enter link description here][1]idSortOrder) {
    return a[0].id - b[0].id;
  }
  else {
    return b[0].id - a[0].id;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I like @answered’s response but for wider support forEach does provide the option to pass a this parameter. So would recommend that for that scenario instead.

```
arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    //your iterator
}[, thisArg]);
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach