# why we need Function.prototype.call , where we can achieve same thing by appending the function to object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

i have seen these examples for call,apply and bind

```js
var fruit = { name: 'Strawberry' }

function showDetails(size, price) {
  console.log(this.name + ' ' + size + ': $' + price + '/lb')
}

showDetails.apply(fruit, ['small', 10])
// Strawberry small: $10/lb

showDetails.call(fruit, 'small', 10)
// Strawberry small: $10/lb

var bound = showDetails.bind(fruit, 'small', 10)
bound()
//Strawberry small: $10/lb

showDetails.bind(fruit, 'small', 10)()
// Strawberry small: $10/lb
```

here all functions do the same thing and check the below code with out using any of these(call,apply and bind)

```js
var fruit = { name: 'Strawberry' };
function showDetails(size, price) {
  console.log(this.name + ' ' + size + ': $' + price + '/lb')
}
fruit.show =showDetails;

fruit.show(small,10); //Strawberry small: $10/lb
```

it worked same as expected so why ,when do we need call,apply and bind.

how to use these functions in ES6 ?

Comment: What  if `fruit` already had a property called "show"? It'd be a mess to always have to add a property to an object whenever you wanted to do this.

Comment: we can check with `hasOwnProperties` right?

Comment: What Pointy said. It could even be that the object is sealed, and then your alternative would not be allowed.

Comment: @user8208248 would you prefer to use `.call` or check `hasOwnProperties` for everything?

Comment: Also object might be frozen `fruit = Object.freeze({ name: 'Strawberry' })`

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, defining the method on the object will be viable alternative in many cases. However, sometimes it is not an option:

#### 1. The object does not allow the method to be defined:

```js
"use strict";
function showDetails() { console.log(this.name); }
var obj = Object.seal({ name: 'Strawberry' });
showDetails.call(obj); // Strawberry
obj.showDetails = showDetails; // fails
```

#### 2. Object already has a property with that name

```js
function name() { console.log(this.name) }
var obj = Object.seal({ name: 'Strawberry' });
name.call(obj); // Strawberry
obj.name = name;
obj.name(); // does not show 'Strawberry', but the function
```

It could also fail if the said property is read-only (with `defineProperty` and `writable: false`).

#### 3. Adding the property influences the return value

Suppose the function performs self inspection, e.g. it counts the number of properties it has:

```js
function memberCount() { return Object.keys(this).length; };
var obj = { name: 'Strawberry' };
console.log(memberCount.call(obj)); // 1
obj.count = memberCount;
console.log(obj.count()); // 2
```

#### 4. Adding the property influences the remaining code

This is especially a problem with objects of which you expect a certain behaviour, like arrays:

```js
function first() { return this[0]; };
var arr = ['Strawberry', 'Banana'];
console.log(first.call(arr)); // Strawberry
arr.first = first;
// ...
for (var i in arr) { // Iterate through array
    if (arr.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        console.log(arr[i]); // Oops, the function appears also.
    }
}
```

## Other examples for `apply` and `bind`

There are other examples where the use of `apply` or `bind` is useful in case the target object already *has* the method:

`apply` may be used with methods that require separate arguments, while you just have an array of values. In ES6 you can use the spread syntax to overcome this, but traditionally, `apply` was the solution for this.

For example, to get the minimum value in an array:

```js
var arr = [5,3,1,6,2];
console.log(Math.min.apply(Math, arr));
```

The `bind` method is often used to pass a method as a callback, but you need it to be bound to your object:

```js
var obj = {
    flavour: 'Strawberry',
    smell: function () { console.log(this.flavour) }
};

window.addEventListener('load', obj.smell); // ......> undefined
window.addEventListener('load', obj.smell.bind(obj)); // .....>Strawberry
```

## ES6 Considerations

Where `this` must be bound, there can still be use for these methods. But with the arrow function syntax, `this` keeps its lexical value, and passing the `this` argument to `apply`, `call` or `bind` on such function has no effect. Often it also becomes unnecessary, as that lexical `this` is often exactly what is needed.

Take the example of getting the minimum value of an array. With ES6 it can be written as follows:

```js
const arr = [5,3,1,6,2,4];
console.log(Math.min(...arr));
```

Or take an example where a method (using `this`) is passed as callback:

```js
class Cls {
    constructor() { 
        this.flavour = 'Strawberry'
        this.smell = () => console.log(this.flavour)
    }
};

window.addEventListener('load', (new Cls).smell); // ......> Strawberry
```

Answer (score 2):

- we need (want) `call` and `apply` because they are much simpler than the alternative (depending on the use case, obviously)
- we need `call` and `apply` because the alternative does not work on objects to which we cannot assign a property (frozen or sealed)
- we need `call` and `apply` when the method is not supposed to be a property of the object during the evaluation of the function

Also we need `apply` because `call` cannot work with a dynamic number of arguments (ignoring new spread syntax), see [What is the difference between call and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1986896/1048572). And `bind` is a completely different beast, see [Javascript call() & apply() vs bind()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15455009/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

> we can achieve same thing by appending the function to object in javascript

You are right as per your example. But in javascript we need to pass functions as callbacks to browser-event-loop-queue to execute async. In such cases the object will be lost. Check below example

```
var fruit = { name: 'Strawberry' };
function showDetails(size, price) {
  console.log(this.name + ' ' + size + ': $' + price + '/lb')
}
fruit.show =showDetails;

setTimeout(fruit.show, 100);
```

Here output will be undefined, so to attach the arguments and context object, we need "bind"

and now we can make above work with

`setTimeout(fruit.show.bind(fruit, size, price), 100);`

Use for apply/call is to execute a function, by dynamically supplying its context and arguments. Check follwoing usage of call.

```
var Array.protoype.forEach = function(cb /*, thisArg*/){
  var T;
  if (arguments.length > 1) {
      T = arguments[1];
    }
  for(var i =0; i<this.length; i++){
    cb.call(T, this[i], i, this);
  }
}
```