# apply method not returning full array value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I made an array to be passed in apply method, I was expecting to return full value of array, but when I used index value of array to give value of that index, array method actually returned index of character:

```js
var obj = {
  name: 'Dogs'
}
var arr = ['India', 'Slovenia', 'Scotland'];

var getanimalsinfo = function(a) {

  return this.name + ' is good animal found in ' + a[2]

}
console.log(getanimalsinfo.apply(obj, arr));
```

Here, I was expecting "Dog is good animal found in Scotland", but I got : 'Dog is good animal found in d'.
    Here d is the third index of India. Please let me know what I did wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`.apply` passes each element of the array as separate argument to the function. I.e. in your case the function is called as `getanimalsinfo(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2])` and hence `a` will have the value `'india'`.

If you want to pass the array as a single argument (equivalent to `getanimalsinfo(arr)`), use `.call` instead:

```js
var obj = {
  name: 'Dogs'
}
var arr = ['india', 'slovenia', 'scotland'];

var getanimalsinfo = function(a) {

  return this.name + ' is good animal found in ' + a[2]

}
console.log(getanimalsinfo.call(obj, arr));
//                         ^^^^
```

Alternative solutions:

- Wrap the argument passed to `.apply` in another array: `getanimalsinfo.apply(obj, [arr])`
- Use a [*rest parameter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) in your function definition: `function(...a) { /*...*/ }`

---

Have a look at the MDN documentation for more info:

- [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
- [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Related:

- [Javascript call() & apply() vs bind()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/javascript-call-apply-vs-bind)

Comment: ok, then how to get this result: 'dog is good animal found in india, slovenia, scotland' using APPLY??

Comment: @user3450590 with `.call` instead of `.apply`.

Comment: @user3450590: If you defined the function as  `function(...args) {...}` and did `' is good animal found in ' + args.join()`. But you shouldn't define the function based on the fact that you want to use `.apply`. You should decide first whether you want the function to be variadic or accept an array as argument. And based on that you choose either `.apply` or `.call`.

Comment: @FelixKling with apply, he should have used `function(arg1, arg2, arg3)` instead of `function(a)` ?

Comment: @Cid: Really depends on how the function should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

```js
var obj={name: 'Dogs'};
var arr=['india','slovenia','scotland'];

var getanimalsinfo = function(){
    return this.name + ' is good animal found in '+ arguments[2]

}
console.log(getanimalsinfo.apply(obj, arr));
```