# Hard binding vs call

Tags: javascript

In my example, do bind and call achieve the same thing, it's just that bind creates a new function?

```
function hardBinding(a,b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    console.log(this);
}

hardBinding = hardBinding.bind(this,a,b);
hardBinding();

function sameAs(){
    hardBinding.call(this,a,b);
}

sameAs();
```

Comment: They are the same, except for the fact that `this` inside sameAs is already not the same as `this` outside it (unless you're not in strict mode and the `this` outside is different too).

Comment: They would be completely identical if you used `.bind(x,a,b)` and `.call(x,a,b)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15455043/2813224

Comment: @zer00ne - thank you.

Comment: `.call(this,a,b)` is same as `.bind(this,a,b)()` and `.bind(this,a)(b)` and `.bind(this)(a,b)`