# Why can't I set the 'prototype' of a function created using 'bind'?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Consider this code:

```
function foo(something) {
  this.a = something;
}

var obj1 = {};

var bar = foo.bind(obj1);
```

Now the following statement doesn't execute:

```
bar.prototype.newprop = "new"; // Cannot execute this
```

As I understood, every function has a prototype object. Then why can't we execute the above statement?

And bar is indeed a function as we can call it:

```
bar(2);
console.log(obj1.a); // 2
```

Comment: What are you trying to do by adding a prototype property to that function?

Comment: @Pointy just trying to understand prototypes and bind

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> As I understood, every function has a prototype object.

Well, there are exceptions to every rule :-) You found one: bound functions don't have a `.prototype` property because they don't need it. When you call a bound function with `new`, it calls the original function as a constructor, using the original's `.prototype` object as the prototype of the new instance.

In fact, since ECMAScript 6 many functions don't have a `.prototype` property with an object, because they are not constructors - they cannot be called with `new` so they don't need it. Among those are

- arrow functions (`() => {…}`)
- methods (`method() { … }` in object literals and classes)
- builtin non-constructor functions (like `Math.sin`)

Comment: Can you tell us, when to use bind method instead of call and apply.

Comment: @BearNithi uh, they do totally different things? [Javascript call() & apply() vs bind()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15455009/1048572)

Answer (score 4):

See the [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.bind):

> ## Function.prototype.bind ( thisArg , ...args)
>
> [...]
>
> NOTE 1 Function objects created using `Function.prototype.bind` are exotic objects. They also do not have a `prototype` property.

Answer (score 3):

The returned function from `.bind()` has no prototype object. You can give it one:

```
bar.prototype = { newprop: "new" };
```

It is not true that "every function has a prototype object".  Every function *can* have a prototype object, but the value of the "prototype" property can be anything, including `null` or `undefined`.

Additionally, there are "special" functions that may not behave like ordinary functions in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

Adding properties to the `prototype` means you want to create an object by using the function as a constructor.

When you create an object like by calling `new` on a function, the `this` value is the new object being created. So it makes no sense to `bind` `this` to another value.