# What is the difference between this.function.bind(this) and this.function()?

Tags: javascript, class, bind

What is the difference between this.function.bind(this) and this.function() in class declaration? For pure js

Comment: [Similar to before?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57974389/what-is-the-use-of-this-function-bindthis) Although in this case `.bind()` just returns a new function, while `this.function()` will execute the function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript call() & apply() vs bind()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/javascript-call-apply-vs-bind)

Comment: I saw something like that document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyPress.bind(this)). So it means if key is down then invoke the callback which is the function that is returned by .bind(), right?

Comment: @Rasul yes. And that function will [use the correct context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback).

Comment: It is clear now Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your samples, this keyword refers to different contexts.

**this.function.bind(this)** returns a new function, where this belongs to the execution context of the class. You may use arrow functions instead to get the same results without bind.

**this.function()** just calls the function, which gets its own context.

Comment: "*just calls the function, which gets its own context.*" unless it's already a bound function, the context would be the current `this`