# Angular 7 why my var is not equal into all my functions

Tags: angular, variables, scope

I have a big problem, I'm sure I had already did that and it worked perfectly...

Here is my code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Map, latLng, tileLayer, Layer, marker, icon, Icon } from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.scss']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  public m : Map;
  public n : number = 3;
  public markerIcon : Icon = icon({
    iconUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.2.0/images/marker-icon.png'
  });

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.initMap();

  }

  initMap(){

    console.log(this.n);

    //this.m = L.map('map').setView([44.8333, -0.5667], 5);
    this.m = new Map('map').setView([44.8333, -0.5667], 5);

    tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(this.m);
    this.m.on('click', this.addDestination);
    console.log(this.m);
  }

  addDestination(){

    console.log(this.m);

  }

}
```

The first console.log in "initMap" return me the instance of my map, BUT the second console.log in addDestination  return me undefined.

I've did 10000000 tests. Spent too many times, please help me !

Comment: Issue with context of `this`. Try with an arrow function. `addDestination = () => console.log(this.m);`

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz so we can debug it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript call() & apply() vs bind()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/javascript-call-apply-vs-bind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `initMap` method:

Change this

```js
this.m.on('click', this.addDestination);
```

to:

```js
this.m.on('click', this.addDestination.bind(this));
```

The issue is that when you're passing the method as a callback, the context of `this` is different.

Read more about [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) on MDN

Comment: Thank you.. I was sure that was a context / scope problem, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Use an arrow function. Instead of

```
  addDestination(){

    console.log(this.m);

  }
```

do

```
  addDestination = () => {
    console.log(this.m);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this using arrow function instead of using `.bind()` on `addDestination()` method.

```
initMap(){

console.log(this.n);

//this.m = L.map('map').setView([44.8333, -0.5667], 5);
this.m = new L.Map('map').setView([44.8333, -0.5667], 5);

  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(this.m);
  this.m.on('click', this.addDestination);
  console.log(this.m);
}

 addDestination=()=>{

console.log(this.m);

 }
```

Working demo : [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/leaflet-3exust)