# Difference between variable and an arrow function

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between a variable:

```
const a = console.log;
a('HELLO');
```

and an arrow function:

```
const a = (str) => console.log(str);
a('HELLO');
```

And why in case of using a class member it doesn't work

```
class MyClass {
    foo;
    str;

    constructor(str, foo) {
        this.str = str;
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    getFoo() {
        return this.foo(this.str);
    }
}

const instance = new MyClass(123, console.log);

// works
const f = (str) => {
    instance.getFoo(str);
}

f('Hello');

// doesn't works -> this.str is undefined
const f = instance.getFoo;

f('Hello');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`variable = classInstance.function` actually just returns a reference to the function in the prototype, not linked to the actual instance, the `this.*` looks for global variables.

If you want to be able to have another variable store the function with the context of that variable, you need to use `.bind(...)` [or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15455009/12101554)

You can also give it a custom context

```js
class MyClass {
    foo;
    str;

    constructor(str, foo) {
        this.str = str;
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    getFoo() {
        return this.foo(this.str);
    }
}

const instance = new MyClass(123, console.log);

// give it the context object
const f = instance.getFoo.bind(instance);

f('Hello');

const f2 = instance.getFoo.bind({ str: "abcd", foo: console.log});

f2("...");

// Equal to the prototype
console.log(instance.getFoo == MyClass.prototype.getFoo);
```