# Javascript Passing variable to an onclick doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

I'm trying to pass variables to another function via HTML generation using Javascript but it doesn't get through. Here's my code:

```
var wer_people_btn1 = document.createElement("span");
wer_people_btn1.setAttribute('onclick', 'SendData(' + user.ID + " ANDINFO " + susData + ')');

function SendData(reply) {
}
```

> user.ID contains "3323"
>
> susData contains "< DATA > (info_user)"

The error I get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

I think the <> brackets are causing trouble here. How do I pass these as a string to my function?

Comment: Did you look at the generated HTML? you have a mess in your generated javascript.

Comment: `SendData(3323 ANDINFO < DATA > (info_user))`

Yup, looks like an error to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass a string parameter in an onclick function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643311/pass-a-string-parameter-in-an-onclick-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because what ever you send, that data has to be a string. So string must be in quotes `'` or `"` but it should not conflict. so make use of Javascript's both single and double quotes or try with only one by making use of escape character `\'`

```
wer_people_btn1.setAttribute('onclick', "SendData('" + user.ID + " ANDINFO " + susData + "')");
```

As mentioned in the comment, only event and element(this) can be passed.

**Better workaround:** The above will create a single string input for SendData, but you want to receive as separate parameters, then the following one works `"SendData(" + user.ID + ",'" + susData + "')");` where the function prototype of SendData is SendData(userId, susData) `//no quotes for user.ID since it is a number`

If you need to pass custom objects, then look at this [SO 1st answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000083/javascript-event-handler-with-parameters), those are the only possible ways I know.

Comment: This comments out my variables, mate. Are you sure the escapes are correct?

Comment: I've not used escapes. but your earlier function would be set like `"SendData(3323 ANDINFO < DATA > (info_user))` but what I made is `"SendData('3323 ANDINFO < DATA > (info_user)')`. Passed value must be either string, object reference, number or boolean. But the earlier 1 is neither. bcoz there wasnt '' quotes. Just check once and let me know, if issue still persists.

Comment: But in this example you are not passing variables. You are passing one string that is hard coded

Comment: @Earthling, check the workaround and SO answer I linked. Hope that may help you.