# How can we pass an element to event handler in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created an `<input>` HTML element using Javascript. Now I want to add an `onblur` event handler to this element dynamically. However I do not understand how I can pass the created element as an argument to the function. Here's my code:

```
element = document.createElement("input");
element.onblur = hello_function;
```

In the above code you can see that the element is created. Now I want to pass that element to `hello_function`. How can I do that?

```
function hello_function(element) {
    alert(element);
}
```

Comment: `hello_function.bind(element)`. Also, I'd suggest you to use `.addEventListener` instead of `.onblur`

Comment: You don't need t pass anything? You already can access that element inside the `hello_function` via `this` or `event.currentTarget`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To achieve this you can wrap the `hello_function` call in an anonymous function wrapper and provide the `this` argument:

```js
element = document.createElement("input");
element.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  hello_function(this);
});
document.body.appendChild(element);

function hello_function(element) {
  console.log(element);
}
```

Also note the preferred use of `addEventListener` over `onblur`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if I want to access the `event` object as well inside `hello_function()`, how would that be passed.

Comment: @asprin add a additionnal event parameter to the hello_function() and to the addEventListener. Demo https://jsfiddle.net/xp5we163/82/

Comment: So it would be `hello_function(event, this);` and declaration would be `function hello_function(evt, element){....}`?

Comment: @aspirin see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000083/javascript-event-handler-with-parameters) for details

Comment: Downvoted because it's ambiguous. `this` has the correct value today, but if someone uses an arrow-function, it will not work. You have the opportunity to explicitly bind the element to the function, do it.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way. Thankfully this website allows you to add your own answer. Also, I'm looking forward to seeing your use of an arrow function which works reliably in IE, whose support is still a common requirement of most commercial and enterprise level websites.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter That makes no sense. Of course arrow functions work differently (that's like claiming "*`bind` doesn't work because someone could change it to a `call`*"). Binding it explicitly instead of just dynamically using it will only be less performant, but has no advantages.

Answer (score 1):

try like this. passing the another variable into a function,

```js
var something="hello";
var element = document.createElement("input");
  element.addEventListener('blur' , function ()
                           {
    hello_function(something);
  
  })
 document.body.appendChild(element)

 function hello_function (element){
      alert(element);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i suggest to use addEventListener, also i think you need to append the created element to the document, something like this:

```
var elem = document.createElement("input");
if (elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('blur', hello_function, false);
}
document.body.append(elem);
function hello_function(element) {
  alert(element);
}
```