# Parameter of a function within the eventlistener: How can I pass it?

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing, event-listener

I am trying to pass arguments to a function inside my eventlistener for my school assignment in the code below. I am a newbie in JS and found out here [Javascript event handler with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000083/javascript-event-handler-with-parameters),  that you can't just pass parameters to an eventlistener's function. But otherwise this thread wasn't much help. Simply because I don't really know JS and didn't understand it. How can I do it?

```
document.getElementById("Content_id").addEventListener("focus", focusFunction ("Content_id",event);});


function focusFunction(elID,event){
    alert(elID+":"+event.timestamp);
}
```

Comment: You are *immediately invoking* that function, you are not attaching it as an event listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("Content_id").addEventListener("focus", function(event) {
  focusFunction(event);
});

function focusFunction(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id + ":" + event.timeStamp); //event.target.id is more dynamic
}
```

```html
<input id="Content_id" />
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! Question: what do you mean with your comment? something like : the event.target.id can change during the event??

Comment: Take a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7mbr30nw/). In that case your selector is class instead of a fix id but you can still use `focusFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the callback into a function, otherwise it will be invoked straight away:

```
document.getElementById("Content_id").addEventListener("focus", (event) => focusFunction("Content_id", event));
```